# Left Join not returning all rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have this query in MySQL:

```
SELECT pr.*, pr7.value AS `room_price_high`
FROM `jos_hp_properties` pr
LEFT OUTER JOIN `jos_hp_properties2` pr7 ON pr7.property=pr.id
WHERE pr7.field=23
```

The `jos_hp_properties` table has 27 rows but the query only returns one. Based on **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479650/why-is-my-left-join-not-returning-nulls)** I think it may be because of the WHERE clause. The `jos_hp_properties2` table has fields id, property, field, value, where `field` is a foreign key to a third table (which I don't need to get data from).

Is there a way to select all the rows from the first table, including the value from table #2 where the field is 23 (or NULL if there is no field 23)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my left join not returning nulls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479650/why-is-my-left-join-not-returning-nulls)

Comment: "select all the rows from the first table, including the value from table #2 where the field is 23 (or NULL if there is no field 23)" is not clear. There also doesn't seem to be any way to interpret it so that it describes the code in the accepted answer.

Comment: @philipxy This is an 8 year old question, **it doesn’t matter**

Comment: The answer more or less ignores your last paragraph & gueses what you meant from your code. The answer has 30 upvotes. The question is a faq including when it was asked and is also the duplicate target of closed questions. So many uninformed beginners come to this question. They will be helped.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Sure. Move the WHERE condition to the JOIN:

```
SELECT pr.*, pr7.value AS `room_price_high`
  FROM `jos_hp_properties` pr
       LEFT JOIN `jos_hp_properties2` pr7 
       ON pr7.property=pr.id
   AND 
       pr7.field=23
```

Comment: Thanks! The answer in the question I linked actually explains this, but for some reason it didn't make sense first time I read it...

Answer (score 12):

You must place the pr7 criteria in the join, not in the where clause.  The where clause works on the entire result set AFTER the join has been performed.

```
SELECT pr.*, pr7.value AS `room_price_high`
FROM `jos_hp_properties` pr
LEFT OUTER JOIN `jos_hp_properties2` pr7 ON pr7.property=pr.id and pr7.field=23
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT pr.*, pr7.value AS `room_price_high`
FROM `jos_hp_properties` pr
LEFT OUTER JOIN `jos_hp_properties2` pr7 ON pr7.property=pr.id
WHERE (pr7.field=23 OR pr7.field is null)
```

Comment: This isn't quite the optimal query - see the other answers where the pr7 criteria are moved to the join.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that when I was typing it and should have changed it, but I was feeling lazy.  This question reminds me of all the programmers who specifically exclude rows and then expect them to magically reappear because they said "outer join."

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to do the select, then use the CTE to do the left join..

```
wrc (parentid, childid) as (
    select parentid, childid
    from placechild
    where relationshipid in  (select id from placerelationship where relationship = 'Winter Region Capital')
),
stw (cnid, coid, capid, st_or_te, sid, scid,wcid) as (
    select s.cnid, s.coid, s.capid, s.st_or_te, s.sid, s.scid, w.childid
    from stcap s
    left join wrc w
    on s.sid = w.parentid
)
select * from stw
```