# LEFT/RIGHT JOIN not returning empty row

Tags: mysql, join

I have a query which uses a self join on 2 tables to return a single row of results. The problem I have is that if seat1 is empty, I don't get anything returned.

```
SELECT seat1.seat_type_id
     , seat1.seat_type_qty
     , seat2.seat_type_id
     , seat2.seat_type_qty
  FROM jos_sv_apptpro2_requests AS R 
  LEFT JOIN jos_sv_apptpro2_seat_counts AS seat1 ON R.id_requests = seat1.request_id 
  LEFT JOIN jos_sv_apptpro2_seat_counts AS seat2 ON R.id_requests = seat2.request_id
 WHERE (seat1.seat_type_id = 6 AND seat2.seat_type_id = 7)
   AND R.id_requests = 8703
   AND R.resource = 3
```

This should return:

```
seat_type_id 6
seat_type_qty 0 <= this is the empty row
seat_type_id1 7
seat_type_qty 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WHERE seat1.seat_type_id = 6 AND seat2.seat_type_id = 7
```

is what removes all rows with NULL values. You should move those condition to the JOIN criteria so that the RDBMS does what you are expecting:

```
LEFT JOIN jos_sv_apptpro2_seat_counts AS seat1 ON R.id_requests = seat1.request_id 
                                              AND seat1.seat_type_id = 6
LEFT JOIN jos_sv_apptpro2_seat_counts AS seat2 ON R.id_requests = seat2.request_id
                                              AND seat2.seat_type_id = 7
```

Comment: @Jeepstone: this is not really a technique... it is how joins work! It is the OUTER JOIN operation that fills rows with NULL values when there is no match, and the WHERE filters apply after all joins have been performed.

Answer (score 1):

Move your where clauses into the JOINs:

```
LEFT JOIN jos_sv_apptpro2_seat_counts AS seat1 
   ON (R.id_requests = seat1.request_id) AND (seat1.seat_type_id = 6)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

when you have them in the where clause, you're matching against the whole row. Doing it in the JOIN will do the filtering only on the particular records being joined.