# Left Outer Join Not Working?

Tags: sql, join, reporting-services

I have a query pulling data from three tables using LEFT OUTER JOIN for both joins.  I need the query to return the left most (Salesrep table) info even if the there is no corresponding data in the two right tables (prescriber and prescriptions, respectively).  When I run this query without the date parameters in the WHERE clause, I get the expected return, but as soon as I include the date parameters I get nothing returned where there is no matching data for a salesrep.  I need to at least see the salesrep table columns requested in the query.

Here is the query... any help is VERY much appreciated.

```
SELECT  salesrep.salesrepid as SalesRepID,
        salesrep.fname as SalesrepFName,
        salesrep.lname as SalesRepLName,
        salesrep.fname+' '+salesrep.lname as SalesRepFullName,
        prescriber.dea_no as PDeaNo,
        prescriber.lname+', '+prescriber.fname as DocName,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), prescriptions.filldate, 1) as FillDate,
        prescriptions.drugname as DrugName,
        prescriptions.daysupply as Supply,
        prescriptions.qtydisp as QtyDisp,
        prescriptions.rx_no as Refill,
        prescriptions.copay as Sample,
        ROUND(prescriptions.AgreedToPay-(prescriptions.AgreedToPay*.07),2) as AgreedToPay,
        prescriptions.carrierid as CarrierID
FROM    salesrep
  LEFT OUTER JOIN prescriber on salesrep.salesrepid = prescriber.salesrepid
  LEFT OUTER JOIN prescriptions on prescriber.dea_no = prescriptions.dea_no
  WHERE salesrep.salesrepid = 143 AND
        prescriptions.filldate >= '09-01-12' AND
        prescriptions.filldate <= '09-17-12'
ORDER BY prescriptions.filldate
```

Comment: What DBMS? (Off topic, but I hate drug reps & drug industry)

Comment: @njk (Off topic) this is not surprising at all, considering a strong media bias against the industry :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You should move the constraints on `prescriptions.filldate` into the `ON` condition of the join, and remove it from the `where` clause:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN prescriptions ON prescriber.dea_no = prescriptions.dea_no
                             AND prescriptions.filldate >= '09-01-12'
                             AND prescriptions.filldate <= '09-17-12'
```

Otherwise, entries for which there are no `prescriptions` end up with `null`s in `prescriptions.filldate`, and the `WHERE` clause throws them away.

Comment: I made exactly the same mistake, misusing `where` as `on` seems to be a common problem

Comment: I am searching for this for past two days. Thank you very much

Answer (score 18):

[Here](http://mssqlworld.blogspot.com/2012/04/observing-true-experts-indifferent.html)  you can find a brief description about query processing phases (it's common for most DBMSes). You will find out there, that for OUTER JOIN:

1. first CARTESIAN JOIN is produced,
2. than the ON condition is performed on result set producing subset of rows,
3. after than outer rows are appended with NULLs on inner table's joined columns,
4. on that result the WHERE clause is applied performing filtering.

When you place the condition within WHERE clause which touches outer tables rows they're all discarded. You should simply place that condition within the ON clause, as that one is evaluated before outer rows are appended.

So, those conditions:

```
prescriptions.filldate >= '09-01-12' AND
prescriptions.filldate <= '09-17-12'
```

should be moved into ON clause.

Answer (score 3):

This [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mtrr6WYvQLSEShaRyKXwKr/0) can be useful for illustrating that:

> a restriction placed in the ON clause is processed before the join, while a restriction placed in the WHERE clause is processed after the join.

Note that does not matter with inner joins, but it matters a lot with outer joins. More details in [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)

---

**Table t1**

```
| num | name |
| --- | ---- |
| 1   | a    |
| 2   | b    |
| 3   | c    |
```

---

**Table t2**

```
| num | value |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | xxx   |
| 3   | yyy   |
| 5   | zzz   |
```

---

**Join condition in the ON clause**

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.num = t2.num AND t2.value = 'xxx';
```

```
| num | name | num | value |
| --- | ---- | --- | ----- |
| 1   | a    | 1   | xxx   |
| 2   | b    |     |       |
| 3   | c    |     |       |
```

---

**Join condition in the WHERE clause**

```
SELECT * FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.num = t2.num 
WHERE t2.value = 'xxx';
```

```
| num | name | num | value |
| --- | ---- | --- | ----- |
| 1   | a    | 1   | xxx   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mtrr6WYvQLSEShaRyKXwKr/0)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `prescriptions.filldate` inequalities are filtering out your `salesrep` rows that don't have a value in the `prescriptions.filldate` column.

So if there are null values (no matching data from the right tables), then the entire row, including the salesrep data is filtered out by the date filters - because the `null` doesn't fall between the two dates.