# SQL - Conditions on two tables with a sum(case when)

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-when

I have a code that gives me close to the answer I want.

Right now the code yields the growth between time for different estimates and it returns non null values for the different years. I would however need it to only sum values in which the underlying companies have values in both of the periods and not just in one of the periods.

```
 Select m.date_Month
    ,sum(case when y.date_year = 2016 then n.EBIT end) / sum(case when y.date_year = 2015 then n.EBIT end) - 1 as 'EBIT Growth 2015-2016'  
 from EBIT as n
    inner join date_year as y on y.date_year_id = n.date_year_id  
    inner join date_month as m on m.date_month_id = n.date_month_id 
where n.EBIT<> 0  and m.date_month > '2012-11-30' and m.date_month < '2017-01-31'
 group by m.date_month
 order by m.Date_Month asc;
```

I'm guessing there is something that needs to be added in either the sum(case when ....) syntax or in the where clause.

A short example to show exactly what I desire:

```
Company_Id  Date_Year  Date_Month  Ebit
1           2015       2014-12-30  50
1           2016       2014-12-30  52
2           2015       2014-12-30  60
3           2015       2014-12-30  40
3           2016       2014-12-30  43
```

Right now the code looks at the table above and takes: (52+43)/(50+60+40)-1

I need it to only take: (52+43)/(50+40)-1

Hence the final output for this specific Date_Month would ideally be:

```
Date_Month    EBIT Growth 2015-2016
.....         ......    
2014-12-30    0.0556
.....         ......
```

The current output (and the desired output for the code can be seen below, the values are however wrong since they include values which exist for 2015 but not for 2016 (and vice versa).

```
date_Month  2014-2015   2015-2016
2012-12-31  0.025866    NULL
2013-01-31  0.043509    NULL
2013-02-28  0.048632    NULL
2013-03-31  1.120582    NULL
2013-04-30  0.076691    NULL
2013-05-31  0.072184    NULL
2013-06-30  0.078506    NULL
2013-07-31  0.088014    NULL
2013-08-31  0.084344    NULL
2013-09-30  0.088520    NULL
2013-10-31  0.090181    NULL
2013-11-30  0.091335    NULL
2013-12-31  0.094102    0.989785
2014-01-31  0.094030    0.011348
2014-02-28  0.096986    0.024370
2014-03-31  0.096916    0.040109
2014-04-30  0.098773    0.044166
2014-05-31  0.099726    0.051751
2014-06-30  0.099677    0.063474
2014-07-31  0.099865    0.071188
2014-08-31  0.101077    0.073944
2014-09-30  0.101028    0.075055
2014-10-31  0.090556    0.079508
2014-11-30  0.083493    0.083621
2014-12-31  0.070896    0.088688
2015-01-31  0.072573    0.095857
2015-02-28  0.077159    0.102403
2015-03-31  0.082023    0.102581
2015-04-30  0.076842    0.096223
2015-05-31  0.088918    0.094773
2015-06-30  0.084905    0.093353
2015-07-31  0.075418    0.086845
2015-08-31  0.061566    0.085217
2015-09-30  0.051807    0.071888
2015-10-31  0.060045    0.066542
2015-11-30  0.072266    0.061107
2015-12-31  0.050182    0.055806
2016-01-31  NULL            0.023453
2016-02-29  NULL            0.029018
2016-03-31  NULL          0.011684
2016-04-30  NULL            0.007700
2016-05-31  NULL           0.012831
2016-06-30  NULL           0.001756
2016-07-31  NULL          -0.001628
2016-08-31  NULL          -0.001095
2016-09-30  NULL         -0.000649
2016-10-31  NULL          0.000707
2016-11-30  NULL          0.015307
2016-12-31  NULL          0.013374
```

Thanks to input this is the code that almost yields exactly what I want, but it does not include the 'Null' value seen in the example above:

```
SELECT
    m1.date_Month,
    SUM(n2.EBIT) /
    SUM(n1.EBIT) - 1 AS 'EBIT Growth 2014-2015',
    SUM(n3.EBIT) /
    SUM(n2.EBIT) - 1 AS 'EBIT Growth 2015-2016'
FROM EBIT AS n1
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y1 ON y1.date_year_id = n1.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m1 ON m1.date_month_id = n1.date_month_id
INNER JOIN EBIT AS n2
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y2 ON y2.date_year_id = n2.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m2 ON m2.date_month_id = n2.date_month_id
ON n1.Company_Id = n2.company_Id AND m1.date_month = m2.date_month
INNER JOIN EBIT AS n3
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y3 ON y3.date_year_id = n3.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m3 ON m3.date_month_id = n3.date_month_id
ON n2.Company_Id = n3.company_Id AND m2.date_month = m3.date_month
WHERE n1.EBIT <> 0 AND n2.EBIT <> 0 and n3.EBIT <> 0 AND y1.date_year = 2014 AND y2.date_year = 2015 and y3.date_year = 2016 
GROUP BY m1.date_month
ORDER BY m1.Date_Month ASC;
```

I am using Microsoft Management Studio.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I've Edited it slightly now, please let me know if you require more information to understand what my question is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider rewriting you query so that you inner join both periods (2016 and 2015) using criterias based on `date_month` and `company_id` which should filter rows where the `company_id` is missing in one of both periods.

```
SELECT
    m1.date_Month,
    SUM(n1.EBIT) /
    SUM(n2.EBIT) - 1 AS 'EBIT Growth 2015-2016'

FROM EBIT AS n1
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y1 ON y1.date_year_id = n1.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m1 ON m1.date_month_id = n1.date_month_id
INNER JOIN EBIT AS n2
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y2 ON y2.date_year_id = n2.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m2 ON m2.date_month_id = n2.date_month_id
ON n1.Company_Id = n2.company_Id AND m1.date_month = m2.date_month

WHERE n1.EBIT <> 0 AND n2.EBIT <> 0 AND y1.date_year = 2016 AND y2.date_year = 2015

GROUP BY m1.date_month
ORDER BY m1.Date_Month ASC;
```

Problems would arise with this solution when you have more than one record per `company_id` and `month`.

---

If you need to include NULL values, just use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`. In that case you get NULL values everywhere, where there is no matching record in following years for the specified companies, because `x/NULL` or `NULL/x` both equal to NULL and the `SUM` function ignores NULL values and equals to NULL only when all the summed values are NULL. So there will be all the records from the base year included in the resultset even if there were no relevant values in the following years.

```
...
LEFT JOIN EBIT AS n2
...
LEFT JOIN EBIT AS n3
...
```

You can also have the first join INNER and the second LEFT, if you need it, and start joining form the last relevant year (2016). In that case you will see only relavant comparsion 2016-2015 and also comparsions 2015-2014 of which some would be null.

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    m1.date_Month,
    SUM(n1.EBIT) /
    SUM(n2.EBIT) - 1 AS 'EBIT Growth 2016-2015',
    SUM(n2.EBIT) /
    SUM(n3.EBIT) - 1 AS 'EBIT Growth 2015-2014'
FROM EBIT AS n1
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y1 ON y1.date_year_id = n1.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m1 ON m1.date_month_id = n1.date_month_id
INNER JOIN EBIT AS n2
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y2 ON y2.date_year_id = n2.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m2 ON m2.date_month_id = n2.date_month_id
ON n1.Company_Id = n2.company_Id AND m1.date_month = m2.date_month
LEFT JOIN EBIT AS n3
   INNER JOIN date_year AS y3 ON y3.date_year_id = n3.date_year_id
   INNER JOIN date_month AS m3 ON m3.date_month_id = n3.date_month_id
ON n2.Company_Id = n3.company_Id AND m2.date_month = m3.date_month
                                 AND y3.date_year = 2014
WHERE y1.date_year = 2016 AND y2.date_year = 2015  
GROUP BY m1.date_month
ORDER BY m1.Date_Month ASC;
```

Comment: thank you, This gives me exactly what I want for one column but when I add another column (following same approach) I can't get the 'Null' Values that I would like to have and hence I only get a time series in which all of the columns have data. Do you know if there is a way to make it so that we keep the same constraint for one time series (2015-2016) yet make it so that another time series can have null values etc. (2014-2015 in end and 2015-2016 in beginning since we will have more values for the beginning of 2014-2015 and more in the end for 2015-2016)

Comment: Thank you, Sadly the code does not give me 'Null' values (nor does changing all of the inner join to left join (or just some of them)). It is highly likely that something is a bit weird with my system cause I know that left join should work. 

However if this query still does not check that the data used exists in the different time periods I can not use it. the optimal would be if there was a way to put the first code you put together with another identical code for another period and make a left join of that, maybe try to incorporate a view instead?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: @CedricVongheer Your system is allright, the problem is elsewhere. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12467854/2224701. I have modified my second example and included 3rd filter in ON clause instead of WHERE clause - that was a mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I've made the code work (although imperfectly perhaps) by following your detailed example and logic. I feel like I've at least partly gotten a better grasp of SQL through your help.