# Left join not honored when data in 2 different S3 directories

Tags: amazon-athena

I have 2 tables. table1 and table2 
Table1 is pointing to s3://bucket/Dicrectory1/year/month/day/hour/file (25 records) and 
Table2 is pointing to s3://bucket/Dicrectory2/year/month/day/hour/file (2 records)
My query looks like below

```
SELECT table1.column1,
       table2.column1
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.column1 = table2.column1 
WHERE table1.year = '2018'
        AND table1.month = '10'
        AND table1.day = '31'
        AND table1.hour = '00'
        and table2.year = '2018'
        AND table2.month = '10'
        AND table2.day = '31'
        AND table2.hour = '00'
```

Even though I am doing left join I am only getting inner join results (2 Records common in both tables).

Am I not doing the left join correctly for Athena?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no corresponding record in table2, all table2.* will be null and this gets thrown away by the where clause. (answer stolen from [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working) )

Comment: If I remove my where clause and add it to my join condition, wouldn't that query scan all the directories, rather than 1 directory?

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - let's look away from the technicalities, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A successful left join in aws athena with minimal data scan.

Comment: Hmm, why? Does it confer more bragging rights than an unsuccessful or non-minimal one? :-)    (nope, still XY)

Comment: Anyway, if you want to have the records from a specific date, I think you can add the constraints of the form table1.hour = table2.hour to ON and leave the specific values for table1 (table1.day = '31' etc.) in WHERE. Or you can rewrite where to accept nulls as well for table2.*.