# Why does a condition in ON clause and WHERE clause make the results different?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, outer-join

These statements have different results, the first one displays 2 results including null answers, whereas the second statement displays 1 results which has no null answers. But why? How does using ON (statement... AND statement...) differ from just using AND, separate from the ON condition? I've read a lot around this subject but don't understand what I read. If anyone could explain it in simple terms I would be grateful.

```
SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_NO, S.SECTION_NO, S.START_DATE_TIME, S.LOCATION
FROM EMPLOYEE E LEFT OUTER JOIN SECTION S 
ON (S.COURSE_NO = E.EMPLOYEE_NO
AND OFFICE = 'RM30')
WHERE E.RECORD = 14;

SELECT E.EMPLOYEE_NO, S.SECTION_NO, S.START_DATE_TIME, 
S.OFFICE
FROM EMPLOYEE E LEFT OUTER JOIN SECTION S 
ON S.COURSE_NO = E.EMPLOYEE_NO
WHERE E.RECORD = 14
AND OFFICE = 'RM30';
```

Comment: If you ask those kind of questions then you should make sure the columns in both queries are equal. In the one you use `LOCATION` in the other one you use `OFFICE`

Comment: It's only a difference for Outer Join. Logically the join is done first and then the Where conditions are applied. In the 1st Select `OFFICE = 'RM30'` is evaluated during the join (i.e. it's part of the join), rows with different values don't match, but are still returned due to the Outer Join. In the 2nd Select the Where does not match the NULLs created by the Outer Join, in fact it's the same result as an Inner Join.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the condition:

```
AND s.LOCATION = 'RM30'
```

(Please qualify column names!)

A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table when there is no match to the second table (as well as all pairs that match).  When there is not match, the values from the second table are `NULL`.

When the condition is in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE s.LOCATION = 'RM30'
```

then `s.LOCATION` is `NULL` for non-matching rows.  So, the condition fails (`WHERE` filters out both `NULL` and "false" conditions).  In other words, the `LEFT JOIN` is turned into an `INNER JOIN`.

Of course, when this condition is in the `ON` clause, no such filtering occurs, because of the definition of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

`Left outer join` can provide result irrespective of matching records but `where condition` filter out result(i.e  it will give result only for matching record)