# SQL query doesn't work in my JOIN exercises

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, inner-join

I am using SQL query but query resulted 12 lines, needs to be 3 lines; I can't figure it out.

Not working query:

```
SELECT g.*
    ,c.TxtFobFiyati
    ,C.TxtTalepETeslimTarihi
    ,c.TslParaBirimi
    ,c.TxtFiyat
    ,C.TslDepoKodu
    ,c.TslOlcuBirimi AS 'Olcu'
    ,j.TxtAmbalajDara
    ,j.TxtPaletDara
    ,g.TxtAdet AS 'ambalajAdet'
    ,g.TxtPaletSayisi AS 'paletSayisi'
    ,j.TxtAmbalajAdi
    ,J.TxtAmbalajNetKG
    ,j.TxtBoxGrossWeight
    ,C.TxtAciklama AS 'KalemAciklama'
    ,G.TxtAciklama AS 'KalemAciklama2'
    ,g.TxtPaletUstu AS 'PaletUstu'
    ,g.TxtPaletSayisi AS 'PaletSayisi'
    ,c.TxtUrunAdiEng AS 'UrunAdi_Ingilizce'
    ,C.TxtFobFiyati AS 'FobFiyati'
    ,j.TslPaletTipi AS 'PaletTipi'
    ,j.TxtPaletDara AS 'PaletDara'
FROM E_KT_SAS_Form A
LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_Form_DtyUrunler2 B
    ON A.ID = B.FORMID
LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_FrmSipUrunEkle C
    ON B.DOCUMENTID = C.ID
LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_Form_DtyTeyitEdilen2 D
    ON A.ID = D.FORMID
LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_FrmUretimTarihiEkle E
    ON D.DOCUMENTID = E.ID
        AND E.TslUrun = C.TslUrunKodu
LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_Form_DtySevkiyatlar F
    ON A.ID = F.FORMID
LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_FrmSevkiyatEkle G
    ON F.DOCUMENTID = G.ID
LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_FrmSipUrunEkle_DtyAmbalajlama H
    ON C.ID = H.FORMID
LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_FrmUrunAmbalajlama J
    ON H.DOCUMENTID = J.ID
WHERE E.TslOnay_TEXT = 'Evet'
    AND C.TslUrunKodu = G.TslUrun
    AND A.ID = 11682
```

Not working result

[image]

Correct result table

[image]

Comment: I would start by formatting that query. It is a hot mess that nobody wants to unravel. You also should use aliases that help add clarity instead of random letters. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: Nasty way would be to do SELECT DISTINCT, better way would be to find out why you have duplicate lines, I suspect one or more of your joins are incorrect

Comment: Your where predicates are turning some of your joins into inner joins. Maybe those predicates should be moved to the join?

Comment: sorry for bad formatting, tring to fix it but i can not reply my own post

Comment: Posting images of data is not very helpful. [Why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)? Also, posting some details to allow others to help would make this better. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: You can always **EDIT** your post

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. On adding problem code that you can't fix, research (the manual & the web). Repeat, minimizing working & wrong code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve]. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working)

Comment: Hi. Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 0):

Step1) Start count with the driver table i.e. the one you have alias as 'A'. Check the count if you get 3. Continue.
Repeat step 1 with each new join and see where your count blows up to 12. That is your troubling join. Comment it out if possible and continue with joins. If you cannot do successive joins then find best solution to bring count back down to 3.

If your sure of your where clause great; else start without it too. If count is more than 3. Pop it back in.

```
  select count(1) 
    FROM E_KT_SAS_Form A
    LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_Form_DtyUrunler2 B ON A.ID = B.FORMID
    LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_FrmSipUrunEkle C  ON B.DOCUMENTID = C.ID
    LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_Form_DtyTeyitEdilen2 D ON A.ID = D.FORMID
    LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_FrmUretimTarihiEkle E ON D.DOCUMENTID = E.ID
            AND E.TslUrun = C.TslUrunKodu 
    LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_Form_DtySevkiyatlar F ON A.ID = F.FORMID
    LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_FrmSevkiyatEkle G ON F.DOCUMENTID = G.ID
    LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_FrmSipUrunEkle_DtyAmbalajlama H ON C.ID = H.FORMID
    LEFT JOIN E_KT_SAS_FrmUrunAmbalajlama J ON H.DOCUMENTID = J.ID
    WHERE E.TslOnay_TEXT = 'Evet' AND C.TslUrunKodu = G.TslUrun AND A.ID = 11682
```

Comment: Hi. If a question gives a query with a sequence of 8 left joins it is safe to say it should be downvoted & close voted as lacking a [mcve], not answered. Besides, this does not answer the question, it is a tutorial on debugging (which anyway should precede research & entertaining writing a question). Moreover there is no particular reason to expect that the count should stay low as joins are applied, so its approach is flawed.

Comment: clearly one of the tables has 1 to many relationship that is leading to explosion in number of rows returned. All the person who asked the question has to do is above. Because if leave the columns in and now have columns from all 8 different tables; then have to comment each one out.
I gave this answer knowing full well user did not supply sample data. Its a path provided to user; if he/she does not want to take it and find answer another way more power to them. ;)