# SQL null values not being shown in results

Tags: sql, date, datetime, mariadb, outer-join

I'm having trouble getting the null values on a SQL Query. This is the description of the problem:

> Gross income by week. Money is collected from guests when they leave.
>   For each Thursday in November and December 2016, show the total amount
>   of money collected from the previous Friday to that day, inclusive.

Here's the code that I've written that should return the weekly income from Thursday to previous Friday, the answer i get is partially correct as the weeks that have income are correctly displayed while the weeks that don't have any income are not displayed. I've tried adding a IFNULL clause but that's still not fixing the problem.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(MAKEDATE(2016, 7), INTERVAL WEEK(DATE_ADD(calendar.i, INTERVAL booking.nights - 5 DAY), 0) WEEK) AS Thursday, IFNULL(SUM(booking.nights * rate.amount) + SUM(e.amount),0) AS weekly_ncome
FROM booking
RIGHT OUTER
JOIN calendar ON booking.booking_date = calendar.i
JOIN rate ON (booking.occupants = rate.occupancy AND booking.room_type_requested = rate.room_type)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT booking_id, IFNULL(SUM(amount),0) AS amount
    FROM extra
    GROUP BY booking_id
) AS e ON (e.booking_id = booking.booking_id)
GROUP BY Thursday;
```

For reference, this is a question found on [SQLzoo Guesthouse section, question 15](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Guest_House_Assessment_Hard). This is the expected result:

```
+------------+---------------+
| Thursday   | weekly_income |
+------------+---------------+
| 2016-11-03 |          0.00 |
| 2016-11-10 |      12608.94 |
| 2016-11-17 |      13552.56 |
| 2016-11-24 |      12929.69 |
| 2016-12-01 |      11685.14 |
| 2016-12-08 |      13093.79 |
| 2016-12-15 |       8975.87 |
| 2016-12-22 |       1395.77 |
| 2016-12-29 |          0.00 |
| 2017-01-05 |          0.00 |
+------------+---------------+
```

I get the same as above but the ones with weekly income of 0 don't show up.

[image: Database diagram]

Comment: OUTER JOIN a calendar table having all possible weeks/dates.

Comment: Post sample data as well and tag the database you're using

Comment: @jarlh ive changed the code to outer join a calendar but im still not getting the right results. Am I joining them incorrectly?

Comment: @SalmanA I added the database ive been using

Comment: Put that RIGHT JOIN last.

Comment: Hi. Learn what LEFT/RIGHT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left/right table rows extended by NULLs. FULL JOIN returns INNER JOIN rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a possibly NULL-extended column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns an OUTER JOIN into an INNER JOIN". You have that. (The inner join after your right join.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to get the Thursdays in Nov 2016 and Dec 2016:

```
    SELECT i AS thursday, i - INTERVAL 6 DAY AS friday
    FROM calendar
    WHERE i >= '2016-11-01' AND i - INTERVAL 6 DAY <= '2016-12-31' AND DAYOFWEEK(i) = 5
```

Just left join your data with this, make sure that you join with the checkout date (booking_date + nights days):

```
SELECT
    thursday, SUM(
        COALESCE(booking.nights * rate.amount, 0) +
        COALESCE(extras.total, 0)
    ) AS weekly_income
FROM (
    SELECT i AS thursday, i - INTERVAL 6 DAY AS friday
    FROM calendar
    WHERE i >= '2016-11-01' AND i - INTERVAL 6 DAY <= '2016-12-31' AND DAYOFWEEK(i) = 5
) AS thursdays
LEFT JOIN (
    booking
    INNER JOIN rate ON booking.occupants = rate.occupancy AND booking.room_type_requested = rate.room_type
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT booking_id, SUM(amount) AS total
        FROM extra
        GROUP BY booking_id
    ) AS extras ON booking.booking_id = extras.booking_id
) ON booking.booking_date + INTERVAL booking.nights DAY BETWEEN friday AND thursday
GROUP BY thursday
```