# How to put conditions on left joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables, `CustomerCost` and `Products` that look like the following:

[image]

I am joining the two tables using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT custCost.ProductId,
       custCost.CustomerCost
FROM CUSTOMERCOST Cost
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS prod ON Cost.productId =prod.productId
WHERE prod.productId=4
  AND (Cost.Customer_Id =2717
       OR Cost.Customer_Id IS NULL)
```

The result of the join is:
[joins result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFSVm.png)

What i want to do is when I pass customerId 2717 it should return only specific customer cost i.e. 258.93, and when customerId does not match then only it should take cost as 312.50

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Move the `where` clause to your `join` clause. `left join PRODUCTS prod on 
Cost.productId =prod.productId and 
Gang.PopulorProduct_Id=4 and (Cost.Customer_Id =2717 or Cost.Customer_Id IS NULL)`

Comment: @scsimon i am not clear .please explain me ..please

Comment: @Saurav what seems to be the problem with the current query? In your question, can you provide an example of what the expected output should look like?

Comment: @scsimon I am expecting a single row result when customerId is passed correctly.i.e 258 and when customerId dose not matches it should find values with NULL customerId i.e- 312

Comment: @Saurav  Not sure if I understand the question 100%... but can you just do select TOP(1) custCost.ProductId, custCost.CustomerCost ... and see if it works

Comment: If all you want is the correct `CustomerCost` based on customer and product IDs, you don't even need to join. Look at my answer. Choose it as the accepted answer if you find it helpeful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. Replace a link to a table by code block formatted tabular text (which should simultaneously be code to create & initialize a table if the question should give a [mcve]).

Comment: @DaleBurrell If we edit we should edit *all* of a post. See my comment above re using text, not images/links, whenever possible. This image or a link to it should not be in this post without text for all its content that can be expressed by text. Either replace an image or a link to an image with text by its text plus--if still supplementally useful--the image or, much better, comment to tell the poster to do it. Please don't reward lack of text. Your edit should not have been approved.

Comment: @philipxy - I made the existing links to images into inline images - which according to everything I have read is an improvement, even if not the ultimate goal. I certainly wasn't about to re-type the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your expected output as follows:

```
SELECT Cost.ProductId,
       Cost.CustomerCost
FROM CUSTOMERCOST Cost
INNER JOIN PRODUCTS prod ON Cost.productId = prod.productId
WHERE prod.productId=4
  AND Cost.Customer_Id = 2717
```

However, if you want to allow customer ID to be passed as `NULL`, you will have to change the last line to `AND Cost.Customer_Id IS NULL`. To do so dynamically, you'll need to use variables and generate the query based on the input.

The problem in the original query that you have posted is that you have used an alias called `custCost` which is not present in the query.

**EDIT**: Actually, you don't even need a join. The `CUSTOMERCOST` table seems to have both Customer and Product IDs.

You can simply:

```
SELECT
    Cost.ProductId, Cost.CustomerCost 
FROM
    CUSTOMERCOST Cost
WHERE
    Cost.Customer_Id = 2717
    AND Cost.productId = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM CUSTOMERCOST c
WHERE c.productId = 4 AND c.Customer_Id = 2717
UNION ALL
SELECT c.*
FROM CUSTOMERCOST c
WHERE c.productId = 4 AND c.Customer_Id IS NULL AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CUSTOMERCOST c2 WHERE c2.productId = 4 AND c2.Customer_Id = 2717);
```

That is, take the matching cost, if it exists for the customer.  Otherwise, take the default cost.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT custCost.ProductId,
       custCost.CustomerCost
FROM CUSTOMERCOST Cost
LEFT JOIN PRODUCTS prod
ON Cost.productId =prod.productId
  AND (Cost.Customer_Id =2717 OR Cost.Customer_Id IS NULL)
WHERE prod.productId=4
```

`WHERE` applies to the joined row.  `ON` controls the join condition.

Outer joins are why `FROM` and `ON` were added to SQL-92.  The old SQL-89
syntax had no support for them, and different vendors added different,
incompatible syntax to support them.