# Left outer join and necessary subquery with date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, left-join

I'm struggling with a left outer join where the right portion, the one that could contain nulls, doesn't show me values. I think the situation is called an implicit inner join. The reason is that the subquery doesn't return nulls but rather nothing for what I'd like to have on my right part.

(This question differs from [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working) in that a subquery to find the maximum date is needed.)

Here is a simplified example:

```
Table Contracts:
customer_id, status

Table Values:
customer_id, value_code, value, begin_date
```

I want to display all customers with status = 'active' and the latest value for a certain value_code, lets say 'volume'. There are more value_codes and the values have a certain date from which they are valid. There can also be no value_code BUT then I want a NULL on the right side.

So here is what I tried to do:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTRACTS C
LEFT JOIN VALUES V ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = V.CUSTOMER_ID
                      AND VALUE_CODE = 'VOLUME'
WHERE C.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
     AND V.BEGIN_DATE = (
                         SELECT MAX(BEGIN_DATE) FROM VALUES V2 
                         WHERE V2.CUSTOMER_ID = V.CUSTOMER_ID
                         AND V2.VALUE_CODE = 'VOLUME'
                         )
```

I can't put the subquery in the join clause, Oracle won't accept that. On the other hand my subquery makes it so that all the rows that have no entry for a value with code 'volume' are omitted. What I want is to have value = NULL instead with all the customers on the left.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working)

Comment: Other questions where to specific. I translated my problem to a minimal description. Also the problem is slightly different from what I found by searching (and I did search a lot). It can't be solved by putting the conditions in the where clause to the "on" clause because a subquery is needed.

Comment: 1. Whatever other problems this code has, it has this problem. 2. What does "Oracle won't accept that" mean? 3. [mcve] 4. You do not explain what output you want given the inputs. Describe clearly enough that someone could leave & come back with correct code. Which is what you are asking. Once you are clear it will almost certainly be a faq. 5. See my next comment.

Comment: A [mcve] includes DBMS (with version), a clear specification, cut & paste & runnable code (with small representative input) (format table initializations as tables) & diffable (hence ordered) desired output. But absolute basics of debugging say: Show that your program does what you expect as it goes through (sub)expressions by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. On adding problem code that you can't fix, research (the manual & the web). Repeat, minimizing working & wrong code. Then ask re the (small) difference between working & non-working examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MT0 suggested using partitioning and sorting by row number helped. Only had to include value_code in the partitioning for my purpose.

So this query finally did what I wanted:

```
SELECT *
FROM   CONTRACTS C
       LEFT JOIN
       ( SELECT *
         FROM   (
           SELECT V.*,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, VALUE_CODE ORDER BY BEGIN_DATE DESC )
                    AS rn
           FROM   VALUES V
         )
         WHERE rn = 1
       ) V
ON     ( C.CUSTOMER_ID = V.CUSTOMER_ID
         AND VALUE_CODE = 'VOLUME' )
WHERE C.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
```

Comment: You should remember and use the terms  correctly. Partitioning could mean Table partitioning, which is a totally different feature when compared to using the partitioning clause of Analytical functions.

Answer (score 2):

Filter the `VALUE` rows first and then `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   CONTRACTS C
       LEFT JOIN
       ( SELECT *
         FROM   (
           SELECT V.*,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY BEGIN_DATE DESC )
                    AS rn
           FROM   VALUES V
         )
         WHERE rn = 1
       ) V
ON     ( C.CUSTOMER_ID = V.CUSTOMER_ID
         AND VALUE_CODE = 'VOLUME' )
WHERE C.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with partitioning (nearly never used that). I had to change it a bit in order for it to work. Since I only want the values with code 'volume' I had to say "partition by customer_id, value_code order by begin_date desc"

Comment: @JayChristnach I did briefly consider `VALUE_CODE` but you did not have an alias before the column to associate it with a table so i did not know whether it was from the `VALUES` or `CONTRACTS` table. Yes, if it is in `VALUES` then add it to the `PARTITION BY` clause.