# Left join doesn't return the Null value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, innodb

Suppose I have three tables

crew

```
+------------+----------+-------------------------+
| EmployeeID | FlightNo | DepartureTime           |
+------------+----------+-------------------------+
|         2  | AA123    | 2018-12-30 09:30:45     |
|         7  | AA123    | 2018-12-30 09:30:45     |
|         8  | AA123    | 2018-12-30 09:30:45     |
```

employeetype

```
+----------------+-----------------+
| EmployeeTypeID | Name            |
+----------------+-----------------+
|              1 | Pilot           |
|              2 | First Officer   |
|              3 | Stewardess      |
```

and employee

```
+------------+-----------+----------------+
| EmployeeID | Name      | EmployeeTypeID |
+------------+-----------+----------------+
|          2 | James     |              2 |
|          3 | Alexandra |              3 |
|          4 | Alina     |              2 |
|          6 | Peter     |              2 |
|          7 | NULL      |              3 |
|          8 | John      |              1 |
|          9 | Frank     |              1 |
```

I have joined these three tables but for EmployeeID 7 where the Name is NULL I don't get the NULL value using left join

```
select crew.FlightNo, group_concat(distinct(crew.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC) separator ',') as time, group_concat(employee.Name separator ',') as crew,group_concat(distinct(employeetype.Name)separator ',') as type
from employee 
left join crew on employee.EmployeeID = crew.EmployeeID 
inner join employeetype 
on employeetype.EmployeeTypeID = employee.EmployeeTypeID group by crew.FlightNo;
```

But I don't get the Null in the crew column

```
+----------+---------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| FlightNo | time                | crew                            | type                             |
+----------+---------------------+---------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| AA123    | 2018-12-30 09:30:45 | James,John                      | Pilot,First Officer, Stewardess  |
```

I want in the crew column James, John, NULL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you intend:

```
select c.FlightNo,
       group_concat(distinct c.DepartureDateAndTimeUTC) separator ',') as time,
       group_concat(e.Name separator ',') as crew,
       group_concat(distinct et.Name) separator ',') as type
from crew c left join
     employee e
     on e.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID left join
     employeetype et
     on et.EmployeeTypeID = e.EmployeeTypeID
group by c.FlightNo;
```

Usually in a query with `left join`s, you need to keep using them.  In this case, I think you want to start with `crew`, because you are aggregating by `FlightNo`.  I don't know why you would want a row for employees that are not on any flights.

The other issue is that `group_concat()` ignores `NULL` values.  If you want to see them, use `coalesce()`:

```
   group_concat(coalesce(e.Name, '') separator ',') as crew,
```

or perhaps:

```
   group_concat(coalesce(e.Name, '<NULL>') separator ',') as crew,
```

Comment: Thanks the coalesce function worked for me. Never heard of it before