# What is wrong with this SQL join query

Tags: sql, join

So all fields and tables are existent and have related data (checked).
Yet it is not giving me any rows in result.

```
SELECT `r`.*, `k`.`keyword`, `c`.`name`, `c`.`state`
FROM `local_rank` as `r`
LEFT JOIN `keyword` as `k` ON `r`.`keyword_id` = `k`.`keyword_id`
LEFT JOIN `campaign` as `c` ON `k`.`campaign_id` = `c`.`campaign_id`
WHERE `c`.`campaign_id` = '6'
AND `r`.`location` = '60602'
ORDER BY `local_rank_id` DESC
 LIMIT 6, 60602
```

When I remove either of the `WHERE / AND` conditions it fetches rows of data.

Comment: share all 3 tables sample data and your expected result

Comment: Which dbms is it?

Comment: Move the WHERE clause 'c' conditions to the ON clause to get left join result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working)

Comment: Hi. Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the offset from the limit, you probably don't have over 60602 rows that matches your query

```
SELECT `r`.*, `k`.`keyword`, `c`.`name`, `c`.`state`
FROM `local_rank` as `r`
LEFT JOIN `keyword` as `k` ON `r`.`keyword_id` = `k`.`keyword_id`
LEFT JOIN `campaign` as `c` ON `k`.`campaign_id` = `c`.`campaign_id`
WHERE `c`.`campaign_id` = '6'
  AND `r`.`location` = '60602'
ORDER BY `local_rank_id` DESC
LIMIT 6
```

Comment: Of course...(don't get how didn't I see that). I guess 16 hours into coding made me miss that little thing . Nothing like having extra pair of eyes to look at it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using "LIMIT" with offset, at least more than 60602 records should be there to be displayed. You can verify this by removing the LIMIT offset and 
counting the number of rows returned.

```
SELECT `r`.*, `k`.`keyword`, `c`.`name`, `c`.`state`
FROM `local_rank` as `r`
LEFT JOIN `keyword` as `k` ON `r`.`keyword_id` = `k`.`keyword_id`
LEFT JOIN `campaign` as `c` ON `k`.`campaign_id` = `c`.`campaign_id`
WHERE `c`.`campaign_id` = '6'
AND `r`.`location` = '60602'
ORDER BY `local_rank_id` DESC
 LIMIT 6
```