# How to get a table value using JOIN without any reference value to it?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables and want to join those tables.
(*) beside column name means it's the primary key, (**) means foreign key

```
//table_document
ID_DOC*      DOC     STATUS
 DOC01       AAA          1
 DOC02       BBB          1
 DOC03       CCC          1
 DOC04       DDD          1
 DOC05       EEE          1

//table_vendor_document
   NO*   ID_VEND**     ID_DOC**
     1     VEND01       DOC01
     2     VEND01       DOC02
     3     VEND01       DOC03
     4     VEND01       DOC04
     5     VEND01       DOC05
     6     VEND02       DOC01
     7     VEND02       DOC02
     8     VEND02       DOC05
     9     VEND03       DOC03
    10     VEND03       DOC04
```

every ID_VEND should have five ID_DOC and I want to know which ID_DOC is missing in each ID_VEND

I using this query:

```
SELECT table_vendor_document.ID_VEND,table_document.ID_DOC FROM `table_document` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_vendor_document 
    ON table_document.ID_DOC = table_vendor_document.ID_DOC 
WHERE table_vendor_document.ID_VEND = 'VEND03'
```

The result is:

```
ID_VEND     ID_DOC
VEND03       DOC03     
VEND03       DOC04
```

and my expected output should be:

```
ID_VEND     ID_DOC
VEND03        NULL     
VEND03        NULL     
VEND03       DOC03
VEND03       DOC04
VEND03        NULL
```

Comment: Hi. Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working)

Comment: You do not clearly explain what you want as output. "which ID_DOC is missing in each ID_VEND" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to be clear. Apparently: Since your example has NULL in ID_DOC, either table could be the right table of a left join; but with non-NULL in ID_VEND, you don't want table_vendor_document as right table; so you want table_document as right table. Also: Why write `table_vendor_document.ID_VEND = 'VEND03'`& only show VEND03 rows if you say "each ID_VEND" & there are VEND02 rows missing? Also: Your title is unintelligible. PS [mcve]

Comment: Do a cross join between unique vendor ids and unique doc ids to get all possible combinations. Then use an anti-join to find the missing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch table ordering. `table_vendor_document left join table_document`.

```
SELECT table_vendor_document.ID_VEND,table_document.ID_DOC FROM `table_vendor_document` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_document
    ON table_document.ID_DOC = table_vendor_document.ID_DOC 
WHERE table_vendor_document.ID_VEND = 'VEND03'
```

Comment: I am still not get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Your "ON" condition makes the query retrieve just the rows where table_vendor_document's foreign key equals table_document's primary key. In VEND03 rows there are just two foreign keys: DOC03 and DOC04. VEND03 rows do not reference any other rows of table_document, that's the reason why you get such result.