# how to solve left join with where clause do not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query using a `LEFT JOIN` with `WHERE` clause, but when I run my query the unmatched data does not display in the database. How can I solve this problem?

```
SELECT tbguru.id, tbabsenpeg.NIK, tbabsenpeg.tgl 
FROM `tbguru` 
LEFT JOIN tbabsenpeg ON tbguru.id = tbabsenpeg.NIK AND tbguru.kodeapp = tbabsenpeg.kodeapp 
WHERE tbguru.kodeapp='Mantri-Lab 1020' 
AND (tbabsenpeg.tgl = '2019-03-09' OR tbabsenpeg.tgl IS NULL);
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Please provide same data, the current outcome, and the expected outcome.

Comment: Maybe you should use INNER JOIN?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the condition on the second table in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT g.id, a.NIK, a.tgl 
FROM tbguru g LEFT JOIN
     tbabsenpeg a
     ON g.id = a.NIK AND
        g.kodeapp = a.kodeapp AND
        a.tgl = '2019-03-09'
WHERE g.kodeapp = 'Mantri-Lab 1020' ;
```

Comment: SELECT g.id, a.NIK, a.tgl FROM tbguru g LEFT JOIN tbabsenpeg a ON g.id = a.NIK AND g.kodeapp = a.kodeapp AND month(a.tgl) = month(now()) WHERE g.kodeapp = 'Mantri-Lab 1020' .  how if i want to display all data for a month. that's my query but unmathced data still not display.

Comment: @SukmoAbadii . . . If this works for your original question, then you should ask a *new* question, with sample data and desired results (and consider accepting an answer for this question).  Your code looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place "where" clause

> WHERE tbguru.kodeapp='Mantri-Lab 1020'

at bottom

```
SELECT tbguru.id, tbabsenpeg.NIK, tbabsenpeg.tgl 
FROM `tbguru` LEFT JOIN tbabsenpeg 
     ON tbguru.id = tbabsenpeg.NIK 
     AND tbguru.kodeapp = tbabsenpeg.kodeapp 
     AND tbabsenpeg.tgl = '2019-03-09' 

WHERE tbguru.kodeapp='Mantri-Lab 1020'
```