# Matching multiple rows in where clause for filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables as the below:

```
Table 1 : Product_Information
```

| Information_ID | Product_Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |

```
Table 2 : Discriptor_Values
```

| Information_ID | Descriptor_ID | Descriptor_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 98 |
| 1 | 2 | 142 |
| 1 | 3 | 29.66 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 2 | 11 |
| 2 | 3 | 14 |
| 3 | 1 | 17 |
| 3 | 2 | 76 |
| 3 | 3 | 85 |
| 4 | 1 | 59 |
| 4 | 2 | 48 |
| 4 | 3 | 35 |
| 5 | 1 | 48 |
| 5 | 2 | 12 |
| 5 | 3 | 19 |

Using the above tables, I am creating a filter page like in any online shopping page i.e. for mobile phone Min and max range of price, Min and max range of internal storage are descriptor and range of values.
Likewise I will select descriptor and give min and max values for it and the matching product will be the result.
If I pass any filter range then the filtered list of products will be shown else all the records should be shown.

I am trying as the below query but not getting the correct output. I am getting the union of rows which matches any of the passed row (#tblFilter ).

```
CREATE TABLE  #tblFilter(
    [descriptor_id] [int] NULL,
    [min_value] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
    [max_value] [decimal](18, 0) NULL
)

insert into #tblFilter values (1, 40.33, 70.33)
insert into #tblFilter values (2, 100.33, 150.33)
insert into #tblFilter values (3, 10, 60)


    select p.*
        from Product_Information p
            inner join Discriptor_Values dv on p.Information_ID = dv.Information_ID
            left join #tblFilter t1 on t1.descriptor_id = dv.Descriptor_id
        WHERE ((dv.Descriptor_ID = t1.descriptor_id
            and convert(decimal, dv.Descriptor_Value)
                between CONVERT(decimal, t1.min_value) and CONVERT(decimal, t1.max_value))
       or not exists (select 1 from #tblFilter))


drop TABLE  #tblFilter
```

Please help me to minimize the result list by filter and show all records if there is no row in filter table (#tblFilter).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Outer Join Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467744/left-outer-join-not-working)

Comment: @Charlieface no this link does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
select p.*
from Product_Information p join
     Discriptor_Values dv
     on p.Information_ID = dv.Information_ID left join
     #tblFilter t1
     on t1.descriptor_id = dv.Descriptor_id
where dv.Descriptor_Value between t1.min_value and t1.max_value or
      dv.Descriptor_id is null;
```

I removed the conversions to `decimal`s.  You might actually need them, but in the question the values look like numbers and the question doesn't specify that they are stored as strings.

Comment: I have tried your solution already. It gives all the records as output.

Comment: @BholuBhaiya . . . Are you sure you are using the correct `on` clause?