# Retriving all records from left table and matching records from right

Tags: mysql

I am trying four queries to retrieve all records from Table1 and matching records from Table2 but my query returns only two records instead of three.

```
Table1:

EmpId name
1     xyz1
2     xyz2
3     xyz3

Table2:
EmpId   dateIn
1       2015-05-05
2       2015-05-05

Required result:

EmpId name   DateIn
1     xyz1   2015-05-05
2     xyz2   2015-05-05
3     xyz3   NULL

select Table1.EmpId, Table1.name, Table2.dateIn from Table1 left join Table2 on Table1.empid=Table2.empid where date_format(Datein, '%Y-%m-%d')='2015-05-05'

select Table1.EmpId, Table1.name, Table2.dateIn from Table1 left join Table2 on Table1.empid=Table2.empid where date_format(Datein, '%Y-%m-%d')='2015-05-05' group by Table1.EmpId, Table1.name, Table2.dateIn

select Table1.EmpId, Table1.name, Table2.dateIn from Table1,Table2 where Table1.empid=Table2.empid and date_format(Datein, '%Y-%m-%d')='2015-05-05' group by Table1.EmpId, Table1.name, Table2.dateIn

select Table1.EmpId, Table1.name, Table2.dateIn from Table1,Table2 where Table1.empid=Table2.empid and date_format(Datein, '%Y-%m-%d')='2015-05-05'
```

Please help.

Comment: "where date_format(Datein, '%Y-%m-%d')='2015-05-05'" is restricting the results to two records. you need to move the where clause and add it as    left join condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> This will work fine.
>       **Sql Query**

```
declare @Table1 as table( empid tinyint, name varchar(10))
insert into @table1 values (1,'xyz1')
insert into @table1 values (2,'xyz2')
insert into @table1 values (3,'xyz3')

declare @Table2 as table (Empid tinyint, datein date)
insert into @Table2 values(1,'2015-05-05')
insert into @Table2 values(2,'2015-05-05')


select Table1.EmpId, Table1.name, Table2.dateIn from @Table1 Table1 left join @Table2 Table2 on Table1.empid=Table2.empid and '2015-05-05'='2015-05-05'--(or date_format(Datein, '%Y-%m-%d')='2015-05-05')
```

> **result**

```
EmpId name       dateIn
----- ---------- ----------
 1     xyz1       2015-05-05
 2     xyz2       2015-05-05
 3     xyz3       NULL
```

Comment: downvote reason: Try adding records with a different datein value to the second table. see what happens. (also, you have a typo: `leftjoin` instead of `left join`, though this is not the kind of thing to downvote for)

Comment: also, this question is about mysql, not sql-server

Answer (score 3):

You want a left join.

```
select t1.*, t2.datein
  from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2
      on t1.empid = t2.empid
```

In your queries, the way you are referring to `datein` in the `where` clause, will automatically eliminate any rows where `datein` is null, ruining the outerness of the `left join`.

If you want to filter on the date, but return `null` for ones that dont match, you have to move it to the `on` clause, like this:

```
select t1.*, t2.datein
  from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2
      on t1.empid = t2.empid and date(t2.datein) = '2015-05-05'
```

Or, alternatively, if you want to put it in the `where` clause, for semantic reasons, you also need to check for `is null`, like so:

```
select t1.*, t2.datein
  from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2
      on t1.empid = t2.empid 
  where date(t2.datein) = '2015-05-05' or t2.datein is null
```

This method has the caveat that it could return multiple rows per `empid`, if `datein` can have null values in the second table.

My personal preference would be for having the date filter as part of the join predicate, not the `where`.

Comment: Wow, it's like you've read my comment to Ash :-) If datein is a nullable column, your third sql statement might return too many rows. I would suggest adding that point to your answer.

Comment: It's worth noting for completeness perhaps but if that field is nullable the design is broken

Comment: Unless this is a simplified version and there are more columns in the tables. if this is the full design then I agree that it doesn't make any sense to make it nullable.