# MySQL query with LEFT JOIN not returning empty results

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have created a calendar table which simply has a load of dates in it. My events table then has dates that line up and if there are no events for a day, I want to return a zero for that. I have the following:

```
SELECT cDate, Branch, IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) as count
FROM Events E LEFT JOIN Calendar C ON C.cDate = DATE(E.eventDate)
WHERE cDate BETWEEN '2018-04-14' AND '2018-04-18'
GROUP BY Branch, cDate
ORDER BY cDate
```

However results are currently showing:

```
  cDate    | Branch | count
2018-04-14 |   1    |  5
2018-04-14 |   2    |  4
2018-04-16 |   1    |  1
2018-04-16 |   2    |  3
2018-04-17 |   1    |  5
2018-04-18 |   1    |  4
```

However I intend for it to display any dates with a count of zero, like this:

```
  cDate    | Branch | count
2018-04-14 |   1    |  5
2018-04-14 |   2    |  4
2018-04-15 |   1    |  0
2018-04-15 |   2    |  0
2018-04-16 |   1    |  1
2018-04-16 |   2    |  3
2018-04-17 |   1    |  5
2018-04-17 |   2    |  0
2018-04-18 |   1    |  4
2018-04-18 |   2    |  0
```

Comment: The answers point out that your question is missing important (yet basic) information. They shouldn't have answered with guesses, they should have commented for you to supply the info. Please read & act on [mcve] & https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/3404097.

Comment: Probable duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2700354/3404097)

Comment: Hi. Always google many clear, concise, specific versions/variants/phrasings of your question/problem/goal/desiderata with & without your specific strings/names/code and read many answers from many questions, which should inform your further googling. If you don't find an answer after applying what you learned and repeating this then ask a question. Use the most frequently productive keywords as tags. Use the best search as a title. Eg "not returning empty results" is just a fragment of what you *mean*; yet googling your title *still* immediately gives relevant answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any condition(s) in the `WHERE` clause that require column from the outer joined table to be non-NULL effectively "negates" the outer-ness of the join, rendering it equivalent to an inner join.

This condition

```
   cdate BETWEEN '2018-04-14' AND '2018-04-18'
```

will only be satisfied by rows that have non-NULL values of `cdate`.

It helps (me) to think about the left outer join operation in this way:

when a row from the left side has no matching rows from the right side, a dummy row is invented on the right side to serve as a matching row. (The join needs that matching row so the row can be returned.) The generated/invented dummy row consists entirely of `NULL` values.

So a partial fix for the behavior your are observing would be to relocate that condition from the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause of the outer join.

That change may be all that is needed to fix the problem, but... I hesitate to specifically recommend that as a solution, because I don't have an understanding of the actual specification.

---

Another suggestion:

As an aid future readers, consider *qualifying* all column references. (We notice the SQL statement is already assigning aliases to the tables.)

From the information posted in the question, we can't determine which table the  `branch` column is from. It looks like `Calendar` might simply be a list of unique dates, so we're going to assume that the `branch` column is found in the `Event` table.

---

I suspect that the desired result would be returned by a query like this:

```
SELECT c.cdate
     , b.branch
     , COUNT(e.branch)  AS `count`
  FROM Calendar c
 CROSS
  JOIN Branch b 

  LEFT
  JOIN Events e
    ON e.eventdate  >= c.cdate
   AND e.eventdate   < c.cdate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND e.branch      = b.branch

 WHERE c.cdate BETWEEN '2018-04-14' AND '2018-04-18'
 GROUP
    BY c.cdate
     , b.branch
 ORDER
    BY c.cdate
     , b.branch
```

Let's unpack that a bit.

We're getting all the dates in the specified range from `Calendar`.  (We suspect/assume that `cdate` is DATE datatype, and is guaranteed to be unique.  And in this query, we're basically using `Calendar` to generate a contiguous set of date values.)

And we're wanting to get a "count" of the number of `Events` related to each particular date from `Calendar`.

Note that the `COUNT()` aggregate is going to return a non-NULL value; if we are counting an expression that evaluates to NULL, the count won't be incremented. We don't need to wrap the `COUNT()` aggregate in an IFNULL/COALESCE/CASE to replace a NULL with a zero..

We're doing a "left join". That means we want the driving table (`Calendar` in this case) to be on the *left* side, and we want the table we're finding matches from to be on the *right* side. If a matching row is *not* found on the right side, a dummy row consisting of all NULL values will be "generated", so a joined row can be returned.

Since we want to get counts by "`cdate`" and by "`branch`", we also need a row source for the "`branch`" values.  (As @Shadow notes, we could use a table in place of the inline view `b`. The purpose of the inline view `b` is to get a distinct list of `branch` values we want returned.)

The `CROSS JOIN` will get us a cross product. That is, all `cdate` values matched with all `branch` values, so we have a complete set.  Five `cdate` values, two `branch` values, gets us a set of 10 rows, the rows we want to return.  We need these rows to be able to return a count of "zero" when there are no matching `Event` rows for a given `cdate` and `branch`.

Again, we're assuming that `cdate` is unique in `Calendar`, and therefore we're returning (at most) five rows from `Calendar`. We're also assuming that there will be (potentially) many more rows from `Event` will need to be examined, to compare the `eventdate` to `cdate`. We don't want to prevent MySQL from making effective use of an index range operation on the `eventdate` column (with a suitable index available), so we avoid wrapping `eventdate` column in a function and reference the bare column instead.

---

We're just guessing at the requirements, so my suggestion may not satisfy the actual specification.

---

FOLLOWUP

We need a rowsource for the `branch` values.  That can be a table, or an inline view query.  Original SQL didn't assume a `Branch` table, so we used a query to get a distinct list of branches:

```
  JOIN  ( SELECT br.branch
           FROM Events br
          GROUP BY br.branch
       ) b
```

The inline view query in my original answer serves the same purpose as the `Branch` table in the revised query. It returns a distinct list of `branch` values that occur in the `Events` table. If an index with `branch` as the leading column is available, MySQL can make use of the index.

The big difference would be for a `branch` value (e.g. 3) that appears in the `Branch` table, but does not appear in the `Event` table. With the inline view of `Event`, we wouldn't return any rows for `branch` = 3.

Comment: The OP does have a branches table, see the comments below my answer.

Comment: @shadow: OP could use `branch` table as a row source, in place of the inline view in my example. (The important point is that we need a list of `branch` values, and a list of `cdate` values, and generate a Cartesian/semi-Cartesian/cross product of those, and then do a join to Event to get a count of related events. That needs to be an outer join if we want to get "zero" counts, and the COUNT() aggregate needs to operate on an expression that will evaluate to NULL when there is no matching Event row.

Comment: Yes, I know. I wrote all these down in my answer :) btw, the OP should use the branches table as opposed to query the events table for the list of branches. There may be branches that do not have any events associated with them, plus the branches table is likely to be a magnitude smaller than the events table.

Comment: @spencer7593 Appreciate the in depth explanation, I will be going through it in full tomorrow (just hit 2am here), however I have just tweaked and tested it and it does exactly what I need with exactly the right result. Thanks.

Comment: @BN83 as I already pointed out in two answers: querying the events table for list of branches is inefficient and if you have a branch that does not have any events associated with it, then the branch will not show up in the report. You should use the branches table you have, not the solution suggested by Spencer.

Comment: Query is now modified to incorporate **`Branch`** table in place of inline view query to get distinct list of `branch` values. @Shadow: good points. For a `branch` value that appears in `Branch` but does not appear in `Event` table, do we want to return all zero counts for that `branch` value, or do we want to omit those rows from the result. Neither of those is an invalid result, what matters is getting an answer to that question, so we can refine the specification. And yes, there is overhead for materializing derived table. An index with leading column of `branch` would benefit performance,

Comment: @Shadow I don't need the branches to show up if they don't have any events associated to it. The only thing I need is that if there is no event associated with the date, that the date date has a result and that all of my other data gives an empty result. This is working and tested as working in my system now. Even if there are no results for that day, it shows the day as empty, and the next day with the right events.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues:

1. The calendar table has the complete list of dates, so it should be on the left hand side of the left join.
2. You do not simply need the complete list of dates, you need the complete list of date - branch combinations.

I assume you have a branches table to store the complete list of branches. I cross join this on the calendar table and then left join the results on the actual events table:

```
select c.cdate, b.branch, count(e.eventdate)
from (branches b join calendar c)
left join events e on b.branch=e.branch and c.cdate=date(e.eventdate)
group by c.cdate, b.branch
```

Comment: Please bare with me if i misunderstand this. I have a branches table, but there is no data in the branches table that needs to be called for the required result, so why do I need to join the branch table? All that table has is the branch ID and the branch name.

Comment: Because you want to get the counts by dates and branches, including those date and branch combinations that do not have any events associated with them.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure why I need to align that with the branches table though as my primary result is to have a row for each date. Wouldn't I just be able to return a Null result which I could tell to be classed as zero?

Comment: It did work, however adding a second where clause `AND EventType = 2` now removes all of the zero results. EventType doesn't have a table, it's just a simple code for the type of event that is taking place... I didn't add this in to the original question as I assumed it would just filter the results.

Comment: You need to move that filter criterion into the `on` clause. If you have any follow up questions, pls ask them separately.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by using a cross join to link up the required dates in the calendar.  And then join that with the Event table to get the counts of eventDate.

```
SELECT c.cDate, b.Branch, COUNT(e.EventDate) as count
FROM
(SELECT *
FROM Calendar C WHERE
cDate BETWEEN '2018-04-14' AND '2018-04-18' ) c
CROSS JOIN 
(SELECT distinct branch from Events ) b
LEFT JOIN
events e
ON c.cDate = DATE(e.EventDate) AND e.branch = b.branch
GROUP BY c.cDate, b.Branch
ORDER BY c.cDate, b.Branch
```