# SQL Server display left join result set as additional columns instead of rows

Tags: sql-server-2012, left-join

I am working with SQL Server 2012, I have a two tables, `Prospects` and `ProspectContact`, with this sample data:

```
ProspectID     ProspectName        ProspectAdd 
-----------------------------------------------
  1            ABC Company         India
  2            XYZ Company         UAE
  3            PQR Company         KSA
  4            JKL Company         INDIA
```

**ProspectContacts** table:

```
ProspectID  CName        CAdd     CDesignation       Email
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1         Mr Sagar     India    Manager            sagar@gmail.com
  1         Mr Saurabh   India    Manager            Saurabh@gmail.com
  2         Mr Swami     UAE      Director           swami@gmail.com
  2         Mr .ABC      UAE      Engg               abc@gmail.com
  3         Mr PQR       KSA      Manager            pqr@gmail.com
  4         Mr XYZ       INDIA    Manager            xyz@gmail.com
```

If I apply left join on the above tables with below query

```
SELECT 
    P.[PROSPECTNAME], P.[ADDRESS], PC.CONTACTPERSON, PC.EMAILID
FROM 
    [PROSPECTS] P 
LEFT JOIN 
    [PROSPECTCONTACTS] PC ON P.PROSPECTID = PC.PROSPECTID
WHERE 
    P.USERID = @UserID 
ORDER BY 
    CDATE DESC
```

I get this result set:

```
ProspectName    Adress  Name        Email
---------------------------------------------------
ABC COMPANY     INDIA   Mr. Sagar   sagar@gmail.com
ABC COMPANY     INDIA   Mr. Saurabh saurabh@gmail.com
```

whereas my **expected** result set would be this:

```
ProspectName    Adress  Name1       Email1           Name2       Email2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC COMPANY     INDIA   Mr. Sagar   sagar@gmail.com  Mr.Saurabh saurabh@gmail.com
XYZ COMPNAY     USA     Mr.Swami    swami@gmail.com  Mr. ABC    abc@gmail.com
PQR COMPANY     KSA     Mr.Pqr      pqr@gmail.com    NULL       NULL
JKL COMPNAY     INDIA   Mr.XYZ      xyz@gmail.com    NULL       NULL
```

Comment: The email data does not appear to be in either of your two starting tables.  From where are you getting that data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have updated the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT P.[PROSPECTNAME], P.[ADDRESS], PC.CONTACTPERSON, PC.EMAILID
     FROM [PROSPECTCONTACTS] PC 
     LEFT JOIN [PROSPECTS] P 
     ON P.PROSPECTID=PC.PROSPECTID
WHERE P.USERID=@UserID ORDER BY CDATE Desc
```