# SQL server left join not returning expected records from left table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, left-join

I have two objects within a SQl Server 2008 R2 database, which I am trying to join together with a left join but I am unable to get the left join to return all records from the table.

- 1 table - tt_activityoccurrence
- 1 view - vw_academicweeks

The vw_academicweeks, is a view that contains for each academic year a week number, and the first day and last day of the week and contains 52 records for each academic year.

tt_activityoccurrence is a table which contains occurrences of lessons within a year, lessons will not occur in all 52 weeks of the year.

With my query I am trying to return all instances from the vw_academicweeks view to return the following information

```
+------------+------------+------------+------------+---------+
| ActivityID | WeekStart  | StartTime  |  EndTime   | week_no |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+---------+
|      59936 | 04/09/2017 | 05/09/2017 | 05/09/2017 |       6 |
|      59936 | 11/09/2017 | 12/09/2017 | 12/09/2017 |       7 |
|      59936 | 18/09/2017 | 19/09/2017 | 19/09/2017 |       8 |
|      59936 | 25/09/2017 | 26/09/2017 | 26/09/2017 |       9 |
|      59936 | 02/10/2017 | 03/10/2017 | 03/10/2017 |      10 |
|      59936 | 09/10/2017 | 10/10/2017 | 10/10/2017 |      11 |
|      59936 | 16/10/2017 | 17/10/2017 | 17/10/2017 |      12 |
|      59936 | Null       | Null       | Null       |      13 |
|      59936 | 30/10/2017 | 31/10/2017 | 31/10/2017 |      14 |
|      59936 | 06/11/2017 | 07/11/2017 | 07/11/2017 |      15 |
|      59936 | 13/11/2017 | 14/11/2017 | 14/11/2017 |      16 |
|      59936 | 20/11/2017 | 21/11/2017 | 21/11/2017 |      17 |
|      59936 | 27/11/2017 | 28/11/2017 | 28/11/2017 |      18 |
|      59936 | 04/12/2017 | 05/12/2017 | 05/12/2017 |      19 |
|      59936 | 11/12/2017 | 12/12/2017 | 12/12/2017 |      20 |
|      59936 | 18/12/2017 | 19/12/2017 | 19/12/2017 |      21 |
|      59936 | Null       | Null       | Null       |      22 |
|      59936 | Null       | Null       | Null       |      23 |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+---------+
```

With the left join I can return all values except the nulls, so that the week_no column is missing rows, 13,22 and 23. I have also tried this with an outer join but receive the same information.

I feel I am missing something obvious but it is escaping me at the moment.

```
select 
    ttao.ActivityID
    ,dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, ttao.StartTime)-1), ttao.StartTime)),0) WeekStart
    ,ttao.StartTime
    ,ttao.EndTime
    ,aw.week_no

from

vw_AcademicWeeks AW
left join TT_ActivityOccurrence TTAO on
(dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, ttao.StartTime)-1), ttao.StartTime)),0))=aw.ay_start
where 

ay_code='1718' and
TTAO.ActivityID='59936'

order by aw.week_no asc
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq, and all you had to do was google your title. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. A where that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on, which you have, removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join". Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join.

Comment: Don't get discouraged Steer. While this is common, it isn't something that is usually covered when learning JOINs and is easily overlooked, even for someone who has been writing TSQL for months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause makes it an `inner join` by eliminating rows [outside of the scope of your](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/47637/inner-and-left-outer-join-with-where-clause-vs-on-clause/)  join. You need to move this logic up to your join statement. Note, I didn't validate your join condiditon (the dateadd...datediff logic)

```
select 
    ttao.ActivityID
    ,dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, ttao.StartTime)-1), ttao.StartTime)),0) WeekStart
    ,ttao.StartTime
    ,ttao.EndTime
    ,aw.week_no    
from    
vw_AcademicWeeks AW
left join TT_ActivityOccurrence TTAO on
    (dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, ttao.StartTime)-1), ttao.StartTime)),0)) = aw.ay_start
    and ay_code='1718' 
    and TTAO.ActivityID='59936'    
order by aw.week_no asc
```

Comment: thank you for that, I tried that a couple of times but my syntax must have been wrongs somewhere

Comment: No worries at all @A.Steer