# JOIN query, SQL Server is dropping some rows of my first table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, outer-join

I have two tables `customer_details` and `address_details`. I want to display customer details with their corresponding address, so I was using a `LEFT JOIN`, but when I'm executing this query, SQL Server drops rows where `street_no` of customer_details table doesn't match with the street_no in address_detials table and displays only rows where `street_no' of customer_detials = street_no of address_details table. I need to display a complete customer_details table and in case if street_no doesn't matches it should display empty string or anything. Am I doing anything wrong in my SQL join?

Table `customer_details`:

```
case_id customer_name  mob_no       street_no
-------------------------------------------------
 1           John      242342343    4324234234234
 1           Rohan     343233333    43332
 1           Ankit     234234233    2342332423433
 1           Suresh    234234324    2342342342342
 1           Ranjeet   343424323    32233
 1           Ramu      234234333    2342342342343
```

Table `address_details`:

```
 s_no   streen_no       address        city    case_id
 ------------------------------------------------------
  1     4324234234234   Roni road      Delhi    1
  2     2342332423433   Natan street   Lucknow  1
  3     2342342342342   Koliko road    Herdoi   1
```

SQL JOIN query:

```
select  
    a.*, b.address 
from 
    customer_details  a 
left join 
    address_details b on a.street_no = b.street_no 
where 
    b.case_id = 1
```

Comment: cutomer_detials?
streen_no?

Please post the actual code, this would just give syntax errors

Comment: From what you posted the behavior you describe is not going to happen.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: And then there's `addresss` vs `address`

Comment: Are you sure this is the full WHERE clause, or is there perhaps also a part `AND B.SomeField = someValue` ?

Comment: I couldn't get sqlfiddle.com to work so I tested this on a local SQL Server 2017 - obviously guessing data types etc. - and your query works fine for me: I get six rows returned, and three have null addresses. Here's the SQL I tested: https://gist.github.com/RupW/68b0b76700fd42cb82a4ecc6c389a198

Comment: Hi @siddstuff add your expected output.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a LEFT JOIN? The behavior you are suggesting sounds like an INNER JOIN

Comment: i tried inner join but it still drops some rows of my first table

Comment: Inner join is supposed to ignore those rows in the first table, that's what it does. Left join is equivalent to left OUTER join, which is why they should show in your case, with null on the right hand not-matched values.

Comment: Is `street_no` unique in `address_details`? If so, why the additional `s_no`? If not so, what is your result supposed to look like for a customer record matching multiple addresses?

Comment: On a sidenote: A table called `customer_details` makes me think that there exists a `customer` table, and the `customer_details` table lists further details for a customer. But it seems that your table *is* the customer table. With this naming convention you would have to call every table `_details`. An order would be `order_details`, a country `country_details` and so on. I'd drop that `_details` part.

Comment: suggest me, how can I form a query so my first table rows do not drops out

Comment: @PeterB it is full where clause

Comment: Are you **sure** you did not use `where b.case_id=1` and mix it up in the question? That would explain why your actual code filters rows, while the code that you posted does not filter (see comment by **Rup**).

Comment: yes, I used b.case_id=1

Comment: Hi. Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. A where that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on, which you have, removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join".

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. Next code question, please give a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Answer (score 1):

Now that it became clear that you ***`used b.case_id=1`***, I will explain why it filters:

The LEFT JOIN itself returns some rows that contain all NULL values for table `b` in the result set, which is what you want and expect.

But by using `WHERE b.case_id=1`, the rows containing NULL values for table `b` are filtered out because none of them matches the condition (all those rows have `b.case_id=NULL` so they don't match).

It might work to instead use `WHERE a.case_id=1`, but we don't know if `a.case_id` and `b.case_id` are always the same value for matching rows (they might not be; and if they are always the same, then we just identified a potential redundancy).

There are two ways to fix this **for sure**.

(1) Move `b.case_id = 1` into the left join condition:

```
left join address_details b on a.street_no = b.street_no and b.case_id = 1
```

(2) Keep `b.case_id = 1` in the WHERE but also allow for NULLED-out `b` values:

```
left join address_details b on a.street_no = b.street_no 
where b.case_id = 1
or    b.street_no IS NULL
```

*Personally* I'd go for **(1)** because that is the most clear way to express that you want to filter `b` on two conditions, without affecting the rows of `a` that are being returned.

Answer (score 0):

I do think that Wilhelm Poggenpohl answer is kind of right. You just need to change the last join condition **a**.case_id=1 to **b**.case_id=1

```
select  a.* , b.address 
from customer_details  a 
  left join address_details b on a.street_no=b.street_no 
  and b.case_id=1
```

This query will show **every** row from `customer_details` and the corresponding adress if there is a match of `street_no` and the adress meets the condition `case_id=1`.

Answer (score -2):

This is because of the where clause. Try this:

```
select  a.* , b.address 
from customer_details  a 
  left join address_details b on a.street_no=b.street_no 
and a.case_id=1
```

Comment: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: If you use where … then it filters the table first on that, if you use and .., then it will become part of the join

Comment: Actually this will NOT produce the same results. This would return **every** row from customer_details instead of only those where case_id = 1. This just isn't the solution the OP is looking for.

Comment: @SeanLange D'oh, yes, you're right. So this is worse.