# SQL Left Join query with Where Clause drops some rows from first table

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I have two tables mobile and company and i wanted to display mobile details with its corresponding company name. I'm trying this SQL left join query.

```
SELECT m.*,c.company_name 
FROM mobile m 
LEFT JOIN company c 
  ON m.mobile_id=c.mobile_id 
WHERE supplier_id=1 
AND c.company_category=A
```

The company table is huge so i must need 
 to use company_category in query otherwise it is taking lots of time.

**Here are the tables details:**

mobile-

```
 supplier_id mobile_name  mobile_color     mobile_id
    -------------------------------------------------
     1           Moto         Red            4324234234234
     1           Xperia       Black          43332
     1           Gold         Black          2342332423433
     2           Smart        White          2342342342342
     2           Jam          Red            32233
     3           Champ        Red            2342342342343
```

company-

```
 company_category          mobile_id           company_name    
    -------------------------------------------------------
     B                     4324234234234           Samsung           
     A                     2342342342342           Apple        
     A                     67                      Sony
```

expected output-

```
 supplier_id mobile_name  mobile_color     mobile_id        Company_name
    -------------------------------------------------
     1           Moto         Red            4324234234234    Samsung
     1           Xperia       Black          43332             NULL
     1           Gold         Black          2342332423433     NULL
```

But I'm getting this output. It drops two rows from table mobile

```
supplier_id mobile_name  mobile_color     mobile_id        Company_name
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     1           Moto         Red            4324234234234    Samsung
```

Please suggest any alternative sql join query. uw

Comment: The answers below are legit. You may still prefer to use a cte that narrow the list of companies first. It might read more straightforwardly than the more complex join condition. Either way this is a common issue especially in older reporting platforms that rely on simplistic graphical links between tables.

Comment: Sure looks like your last question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206622/join-query-sql-server-is-dropping-some-rows-of-my-first-table Although this one has better details.

Comment: @siddstuff - you should add the `CREATE TABLE ...` and `INSERT INTO` statements that provide clarity on what you're attempting, along with the query you currently have that doesn't work properly.   [edit] those details into your question, please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Comment: Hi. Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. A where that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on, which you have, removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join".

Comment: This is a faq. (Eg google your title.) Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. Also please read & act on [mcve]. That includes a clear specification in words of how output is a function of input--what an example is an example *of*.

Answer (score 1):

you should not use a left join table column in a where clause (c.company_category=A )   try add  the condtion to ON clause

```
  select m.*
      ,c.company_name 
  from mobile m 
  left join company c on m.mobile_id=c.mobile_id  
      AND  supplier_id=1 
        and c.company_category=A
```

if you use a left join column in where condition this work as an inner join  ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `where` criteria to the `join`.  As is, it's negating the `outer join`:

```
select m.*,c.company_name 
from mobile m 
    left join company c on m.mobile_id=c.mobile_id 
                       and c.company_category='A'
where m.supplier_id=1
```

However, this won't give you `samsung` since its `company_category` is `b` in your sample data.

---

Based on your comment, this isn't going to fix any performance problems you are experiencing, just return the missing rows.  Instead you should look at your `execution plan` and make sure you have appropriate `indices` on both tables.  I would suggest the following:

```
mobile (mobile_id, supplier_id)
company (mobile_id, company_category)
```

Comment: i have already tried it, As I mentioned earlier in my question, company table is huge, this query is taking too much time, nearly 1 hrs, to display 2073 mobile records

Comment: @siddstuff This isn't going to speed up your query, it's just going to fix your missing rows.  For performance related issues, make sure you have the appropriate indices on your tables -- `mobile_id` on both, and `company_category` on `company` and `supplier_id` on `mobile`.

Answer (score 0):

Your expected result will never occour:

Because `supplier_id = 1 and c.company_category = A` in this cenario will return nothing.

Maybe your cenario is wrong or just remove your last clausule to get the expected result:

`... and c.company_category = 'A'`

One alternative is try something like this:

```
SELECT m.*, c.company_name FROM mobile m 
LEFT JOIN company c ON m.mobile_id = c.mobile_id 
WHERE supplier_id = 1 
AND (c.company_category = 'A' OR c.company_category IS NULL)
```

Live example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/187ead/13