# Is it possible to filter in a left join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have three tables, Clients, Bills and BillsStates. I would like to get always the client and if it has bills, only the bills that can be modified. I am trying something like that:

```
select * from Clients
left join Bills on Bills.IDClient = Clients.IDClient
left join BillsStates on BillsStates.IDBillState = Bills.IDState
and BillsStates.AllowModify = 1
```

The problem with that is that I get all the bills of the client, no matter if they can be modified or not.

I have tried to with a right join, but in this case I have not get any result.

Is it possible with joins or perhaps I need some subquery? I would prefer a solution with joins, but if there is no way to do it in this way, I would accept another solution.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. (Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.)

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. A where that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on, which you have, removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join".

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. Please read & act on the downvote arrow mouseover text & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2700354/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query simply replaces `BillsStates.*` with null values where `BillsStates.AllowModify = 1` condition fails:

```
| IDClient | Name | IDClient | IDState | Name   | IDBillState | AllowModify |
|----------|------|----------|---------|--------|-------------|-------------|
| 1        | John | 1        | 1       | Bill 1 | NULL        | NULL        |
| 1        | John | 1        | 2       | Bill 2 | 2           | 1           |
| 2        | Jane | NULL     | NULL    | NULL   | NULL        | NULL        |
```

Rearrange the join type and condition to get the desired result:

```
SELECT *
FROM Clients
LEFT JOIN (Bills
INNER JOIN BillsStates ON BillsStates.IDBillState = Bills.IDState) ON Bills.IDClient = Clients.IDClient AND BillsStates.AllowModify = 1;
```

```
| IDClient | Name | IDClient | IDState | Name   | IDBillState | AllowModify |
|----------|------|----------|---------|--------|-------------|-------------|
| 1        | John | 1        | 2       | Bill 2 | 2           | 1           |
| 2        | Jane | NULL     | NULL    | NULL   | NULL        | NULL        |
```

Comment: The parentheses are optional. Effectively, `JOIN` and `ON` play a similar role to parentheses. To work out which `JOIN` a particular `ON` clause relates to, you work backwards until you find a `JOIN` that hasn't yet had an `ON` clause related to it (in the same way you find which `(` matches a `)` by working back until you find an unmatched one)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes but it is more readable that way (someone earlier asked question similar to what is JOIN JOIN ON ON and everyone was confused).

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from Clients
left join Bills
    inner join BillsStates on BillsStates.IDBillState = Bills.IDState
on Bills.IDClient = Clients.IDClient
and BillsStates.AllowModify = 1
```

The problem you have is that you only cause the `BillsStates` record to be excluded, because your filter is only in its join condition. Instead, you can re-order and move it into `Bills`'s join condition.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
select * from Clients
    left join 
        ( select * from Bills 
            inner join BillsStates on BillsStates.IDBillState = Bills.IDState
                and BillsStates.AllowModify = 1
        ) B ON  B.IDClient = Clients.IDClient
```

Answer (score 0):

use inner join between bills and BillsStates instead left join and do left join with client

```
select c.* from Clients c
left join Bills b on b.IDClient = c.IDClient
inner join BillsStates bs 
on bs.IDBillState = b.IDState  and   b.AllowModify = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than joining on a subquery, you can also re-arrange the order of joins

```
SELECT c.*, b.*, bs.* -- Todo: only the relevant columns
FROM Bills b
JOIN BillsStates bs ON BillsStates.IDBillState = Bills.IDState
RIGHT JOIN Clients c ON b.IDClient = c.IDClient
```