# Left join two tables and group by common ID between the two and a common ID between all three

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I have three tables (two of them are actually 'views'). I want to left join tables 2 and 3 and group them by two of their common columns and then do some counts. I've been struggling all night and I'm just about to throw my laptop out of the window

Here are my three tables:

```
+-----------------------+
| Features              |
+-----------------------+
| featureId | title     |
+-----------+-----------+
| feature1  | Feature 1 |
+-----------+-----------+
| feature2  | Feature 2 |
+-----------+-----------+
| feature3  | Feature 2 |
+-----------+-----------+


+--------------------------+--------+
| Tasks                    |        |
+--------------------------+--------+
| featureId | workstreamId | title  |
+-----------+--------------+--------+
| feature1  | workstream1  | Task 1 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+
| feature2  | workstream2  | Task 2 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+
| feature2  | workstream3  | Task 3 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+
| feature2  | workstream3  | Task 3 |
+-----------+--------------+--------+

+--------------------------+-------+
| Jobs                     |       |
+--------------------------+-------+
| featureId | workstreamId | title |
+-----------+--------------+-------+
| feature3  | workstream1  | Job 1 |
+-----------+--------------+-------+
| feature2  | workstream2  | Job 2 |
+-----------+--------------+-------+
| feature2  | workstream3  | Job 3 |
+-----------+--------------+-------+
```

And this is the result I want to get to:

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| featureId | workstreamId | taskCount | jobCount |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| feature1  | workstream1  | 1         | 0        |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| feature2  | workstream2  | 1         | 1        |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| feature2  | workstream3  | 2         | 1        |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
| feature3  | workstream1  | 0         | 1        |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+----------+
```

I want to group by featureId and workstreamId - this combination should be unique in the results. I feel like this should be really easy but I just can't figure it out.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    f.title, 
    t.workstreamId,
    t.taskCount,
    j.jobCount
FROM features f
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT  
                featureId, 
                workstreamId,
                COUNT(workstreamId) AS taskCount
        FROM tasks
        GROUP BY workstreamId, featureId
    ) AS t
ON t.featureId = f.featureId
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT  
                featureId,
                workstreamId,
                COUNT(workstreamId) AS jobCount
        FROM jobs
        GROUP BY featureId, workstreamId
    ) AS j
ON j.featureId = f.featureId
```

Any help welcome :-)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Comment: Learn what left join on returns: inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Always know what inner join you want as part of a left join. A where that requires a right table column to be not null after a left join on, which you have, removes any rows extended by nulls, ie leaves only inner join on rows, ie "turns outer join into inner join".

Comment: When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve]. That includes justifying "minimal code with a problem" for required functionality by finding a maximal part of that code that works for part of that functionality. Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions. Please read & act on [ask] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is by JOINing `features` to a UNION of the `tasks` and `jobs` tables and doing COUNTS on the different titles. The trick is that in the UNION, we have `NULL` for jobtitle from the `tasks` table, and `NULL` for tasktitle from the `jobs` table, thus allowing the counts to add correctly for each type:

```
SELECT f.featureId, u.workstreamId, COUNT(u.tasktitle) AS taskCount, COUNT(u.jobtitle) AS jobCOunt
FROM features f
JOIN (SELECT featureId, workstreamId, 'Task' AS tasktitle, NULL AS jobtitle
      FROM tasks
      UNION ALL
      SELECT featureId, workstreamId, NULL AS tasktitle, 'Job' AS jobtitle
      FROM jobs) u
ON u.featureId = f.featureId
GROUP BY f.featureId, u.workstreamId
ORDER BY f.featureId
```

Output:

```
featureId   workstreamId    taskCount   jobCOunt
feature1    workstream1     1           0
feature2    workstream2     1           1
feature2    workstream3     2           0
feature3    workstream1     0           1
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04555/4)

Comment: This can fail if the titles are nullable and contain nulls. But it can be fixed by using a non null constants instead of the actual `title` in the `UNION ALL`ed subqueries.

Comment: @stickybit agreed, although what would be the point of a NULL title? But it's a good suggestion anyway, so I'll edit to reflect. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm not a dev so I only dip into SQL when I have to - I'd genuinely never heard of UNION before so this is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a full table by `Tasks` and `Jobs` tables.

next step writes two `LEFT JOIN` subquery for `Tasks` and `Jobs` base on the full table, then get `count`

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT distinct t1.featureId,t1.workstreamId
    FROM (
        select featureId,workstreamId from Tasks
        UNION ALL
        select featureId,workstreamId from Jobs
    ) t1 
) 

SELECT t1.featureId,t1.workstreamId,JobsCnt,TasksCnt
FROM 
(
    SELECT t1.featureId,t1.workstreamId,COUNT(t3.title)JobsCnt  
    FROM CTE t1 
    LEFT JOIN Jobs t3 
    on t1.featureId = t3.featureId and t1.workstreamId = t3.workstreamId
    GROUP By t1.featureId,t1.workstreamId
)t1 join 
(
    SELECT t1.featureId,t1.workstreamId,COUNT(t3.title)TasksCnt 
    FROM CTE t1 
    LEFT JOIN Tasks t3 
    on t1.featureId = t3.featureId and t1.workstreamId = t3.workstreamId
    GROUP By t1.featureId,t1.workstreamId
) t2 on t1.featureId = t2.featureId and t1.workstreamId = t2.workstreamId
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0b1947e839e04ec18b3cf7e4b77559d7)

Comment: This fails if the titles are nullable and contain nulls: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=39b250b1b68b3bfdfd2d7bdd5b82a439

Answer (score 0):

`FULL JOIN` the subqueries first and then `LEFT JOIN` the result to `features`.

```
SELECT f.featureid,
       coalesce(t.workstreamid, j.workstreamid) workstreamid,
       coalesce(t.count, 0) taskcount,
       coalesce(j.count, 0) jobcount
       FROM features f
            LEFT JOIN ((SELECT featureid,
                               workstreamid,
                               count(*) count
                               FROM tasks
                               GROUP BY featureid,
                                        workstreamid) t
                       FULL JOIN (SELECT featureid,
                                         workstreamid,
                                         count(*) count
                                         FROM jobs
                                         GROUP BY featureid,
                                                  workstreamid) j
                                 ON t.featureid = j.featureid
                                    AND t.workstreamid = j.workstreamid)
                      ON coalesce(t.featureid, j.featureid)  = f.featureid;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=b4aaacaa97e670cba327710e379b08e2)

It also works, when the titles are nullable and contain nulls: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=53f5150a7faa5e2ebfb48c36b4ee8b58)