# Using coalesce with left joins to populate master table with most recent data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, coalesce

I have 3 tables, 1 master and 2 tables containing the most recent data that should be populated (update) into the master table.

For this I need to create a transform view, that left joins the two tables with the master. For each value I should use the COALESCE function to always pick the value from one of the two tables with the most recent data, before the value in the master table.

Some fields only exist in the master table and some needs to be updated with the new data from the two other tables.

So far I've been using the COALESCE function like so:

```
COALESCE(System.tMirror_Roadpiece.Roadcode, System.tMirror_MasterTable.Roadcode)
```

This should select the value from the tMirror_Roadpiece table if it is not null.
My problem is that I am unsure how to correctly join the tables, while making sure my COALESCE functions work as intended.

Currently my joins look like this:

```
FROM [System].[tMirror_Roadpiece] 
left join System.tMirror_MasterTable on System.tMirror_Roadpiece.Id = System.tMirror_MasterTable.Id
left join System.tMirror_Zipcodes on System.tMirror_MasterTable.Zipcode = System.tMirror_Zipcodes.Zipcode
```

But when I execute my SELECT statement I get no data back. How should I best structure my joins to update my master table with the data in the other two tables? One table is joined on the Id, while the other is joined on Zipcode.

My intended output is a master table with relevant data updated from the two other tables, while leaving the rest of the data in the master untouched.

Let me know if you need more information.

Edit: Sample data

Master table data (CSV):

```
123,1,2015-05-07T13:00:48.623,2015-05-07T13:00:48.623,3446,Hospitalsringen,Hospitalsringen,68,,,,5260,Odense S,,,0461,Odense,350455,"Hollufgård Hgd., Fraugde",1f,704050,590541.26,6135939.39,55.36141744,10.42832236,A,5,TN,200,100m_61359_5905,1km_6135_590,10km_613_59,2015-05-07T13:00:49.533,00000667-2566-47c9-9ba0-f5ec6b8ce50f,1,2015-05-07T13:00:48.533,2018-07-04T18:00:00.000,1083,Region Syddanmark,"Hollufgård Hgd., Fraugde",04613436__68_______,9148,Tornbjerg,1465,Fyns Politi,1135,Retten i Odense,0043,Odense Syd,Byzone,350455,1f,704050,04613436__68,22.1,d90e9338-0470-41bc-8ecb-6f71dd912ff0,11604d86-af45-11e7-847e-066cff24d637,Ekstern,B,V0,10.42845878,55.36232181,25,Rosengårdskolen,1,,02da5b79-929c-f1b5-e053-d280220ac400
```

Edit: SQL code

```
SELECT System.tMirror_MasterTable.[Infohub_RowId]
      ,System.tMirror_MasterTable.[Infohub_CreatedDate]
      ,System.tMirror_MasterTable.[Infohub_ValidityDate] AS [Infohub_ModifiedDate]
      ,System.tMirror_MasterTable.Infohub_HasChanged
      ,COALESCE(System.tMirror_Roadpiece.Id, System.tMirror_MasterTable.Id)
      ,[Status]
      ,System.tMirror_MasterTable.[Oprettet]
      ,System.tMirror_MasterTable.[Aendret]
      ,COALESCE(System.tMirror_Roadpiece.Vejkode, System.tMirror_MasterTable.Vejkode)
      ,COALESCE(System.tMirror_Roadpiece.Vejnavn, System.tMirror_MasterTable.Vejkode)
      ,COALESCE(System.tMirror_Zipcodes.Zipcode, System.tMirror_MasterTable.Zipcode)
      ,COALESCE(System.tMirror_Zipcodes.Zipcodenavn, System.tMirror_MasterTable.Zipcodenavn)
      ,COALESCE(System.tMirror_Roadpiece.Kommunekode, System.tMirror_MasterTable.Kommunekode)
      ,System.tMirror_MasterTable.[Kommunenavn]
      ,System.tMirror_MasterTable.[Regionskode]
      ,System.tMirror_MasterTable.[Regionsnavn]
      ,COALESCE(System.tMirror_Roadpiece.Navngivenvej_id, System.tMirror_MasterTable.Navngivenvej_id)
  FROM 
    [System].[tMirror_Roadpiece] left join System.tMirror_MasterTable on System.tMirror_Roadpiece.Id = System.tMirror_MasterTable.Id
    left join System.tMirror_Zipcodes on System.tMirror_MasterTable.Zipcode = System.tMirror_Zipcodes.Zipcode
  WHERE 
    System.tMirror_MasterTable.Infohub_HasChanged = 1
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: If you're not getting data then your sql must be throwing an error. The joins are left joins so at a minimum you should be getting all the data from the tMirror_Roadpiece table.

Comment: @DeanOC that doesn't have to be the case. Not getting data may mean there is 0 rows in the output, but no error. Also, entire SQL is not posted in here - it may have left joins, which then in the WHERE clause are being transformed into inner joins.

Comment: this condtion is wrong System.tMirror_Roadpiece.Id = System.tMirror_MasterTable.Id it ha to be System.tMirror_Roadpiece. (foreign  key column) = System.tMirror_MasterTable.Id

Comment: @KamilG. If OP hasn't posted all the relevant code then yes that could be the issue. The point I was trying to make is that left joins will never reduce the amount of rows returned from the primary table, you will just get empty columns.

Comment: A hint: Try to give your join columns an Alias like System.tMirror_RoadPiece as RP - Its shorter to write and easier to read :)

Comment: Breakdown: When you need to breakdown your query to see the issues. I would start by removing your zipcode join. And concentrate on roadpiece and your mastertable. Does your roadpiece table have an id like 123 as you show? We cannot know how you sshould join your data unless you provide us with some sample data or you in fact know the logical businesskeys.

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes a clear specification & explanation & expected output & code we can cut & paste & run. Re specification: This post does not clearly say how output is to be a function of input. You couldn't give this to someone and expect them to code a query.

Comment: PS Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions--including that arguments passed to each function/operator meet its requirements--by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. Part of finding a MCVE is finding a maximal working example for partial functionality. Ask about the (small) difference between the examples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows) This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Leth: Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON, which you have, removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". @KamilG. Even the code fragment in the first version of this post (still present as the small join code block) exhibits "turning left join into right join" because a right table column is part of an equality in the 2nd join.