# KSQL : Left Join with Not Equal where condition is not satisfying the result

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

Please find the below issue and confirm for the same.

Step-01 :
Based on the joining condition , getting the value from both table and populating. 
As no matching value in table B, all columns are being populated with NULL Value.

Column: B.OP_TYPE,B.DEMO_ID

```
ksql> SELECT PLAN_ID,A_OP_TYPE,B.OP_TYPE,A.PRIMARY_DEMO_ID,B.DEMO_ID \
FROM TBL_PLN_PRO_DIV_SDIV A \
LEFT JOIN  TBL_MS_TARGET_GROUP11 B \
ON (A.PRIMARY_DEMO_ID=B.DEMO_ID);
382591 | U | null | 3085 | null
```

Same select query with where condition is giving the same result as expected .

```
ksql> SELECT PLAN_ID,A_OP_TYPE,B.OP_TYPE,A.PRIMARY_DEMO_ID,B.DEMO_ID \
FROM TBL_PLN_PRO_DIV_SDIV A \
LEFT JOIN  TBL_MS_TARGET_GROUP11 B \
ON (A.PRIMARY_DEMO_ID=B.DEMO_ID) WHERE B.OP_TYPE IS NULL;
382591 | U | null | 3085 | null
```

But when we tried to select with Not Equal where condition , respective query is not giving the proper result. 
B.OP_TYPE != 'D' - This is where condition which include B.OP_TYPE is null

```
ksql> SELECT PLAN_ID,A_OP_TYPE,B.OP_TYPE,A.PRIMARY_DEMO_ID,B.DEMO_ID \
FROM TBL_PLN_PRO_DIV_SDIV A \
LEFT JOIN  TBL_MS_TARGET_GROUP11 B \
ON (A.PRIMARY_DEMO_ID=B.DEMO_ID) WHERE B.OP_TYPE != 'D';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Comment: Hi. Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: What exactly is your question? Also you didn't just use != instead of =, you changed an ON to a WHERE. PS Please read the edit help about code block format & format your code readably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've described so far is not inconsistent with how SQL behaves. The important thing is that NULL means no value. So `FOO != 'B'` does *not* match where `FOO` is `NULL`.

You've not provided sample data for `TBL_PLN_PRO_DIV_SDIV` and `TBL_MS_TARGET_GROUP11` so it's hard to help definitively here.

If your query didn't return rows where `A_OP_TYPE != 'D'` then I'd agree something wasn't right, because you've shown that there are rows where `A_OP_TYPE='U'` (i.e. `!= 'D'`). But, if you have no matching records from `TBL_MS_TARGET_GROUP11` in which the `OP_TYPE` has a value other than `D`, you won't get a match.

Comment: Thanks Robin . You are right . I checked in RDBMS and saw same behavioral .

Comment: Great—it's polite to mark my answer as correct (if it was), or at least upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Employee Table:

select empno,ename,job,deptno from emp1;

7839    KING    PRESIDENT   10
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER 30
7902    FORD    ANALYST 20
7369    SMITH   CLERK   20

select * from dept1;

10  ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK
30  SALES   CHICAGO

Left join without any where condition :

```
select empno,ename,job,a.deptno,a.DEPTNO,DNAME from emp1 a left join dept1 b on (a.DEPTNO = b.DEPTNO)

7839    KING    PRESIDENT   10  10  ACCOUNTING
7698    BLAKE   MANAGER     30  30  SALES
7369    SMITH   CLERK       20  20  
7902    FORD    ANALYST     20  20  

where condition with Null value 

select empno,ename,job,a.deptno,a.DEPTNO,DNAME from emp1 a left join dept1 b on (a.DEPTNO = b.DEPTNO) where DNAME is null;

7369    SMITH   CLERK   20  20  
7902    FORD    ANALYST 20  20  

select empno,ename,job,a.deptno,a.DEPTNO,DNAME from emp1 a left join dept1 b on (a.DEPTNO = b.DEPTNO) where DNAME != 'ACCOUNTING';
```

7698    BLAKE   MANAGER 30  30  SALES