# LEFT OUTER JOIN PostgreSQL works as INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

The following query works properly

```
SELECT "employee"."id",
       "employee"."created",
       (SELECT SUM(minutes) FROM jobs_job AS job WHERE job.employee_id = employee.id AND job.job_date BETWEEN '2018-10-21' AND '2018-10-30')
FROM users_employee AS employee
    INNER JOIN users_user AS users ON (employee.user_id = users.id)
WHERE NOT ("users"."status" = 'F')
GROUP BY
    employee.id
```

And I get proper data (NULL for people without records in JOB table

However if I reconstruct the same query into **LEFT OUTER JOIN**

```
SELECT "employee"."id",
       "employee"."created",
       SUM(job.minutes) AS job_minutes
FROM users_employee AS employee
    INNER JOIN users_user AS users ON (employee.user_id = users.id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs_job AS job on employee.id = job.employee_id
WHERE NOT ("users"."status" = 'F') AND job.job_date BETWEEN '2018-10-21' AND '2018-10-30'
GROUP BY
    employee.id
```

I get **112** rows instead of **142** in original query and only records that exist in Job table

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Please see [mcve] re code questions.

Comment: @SABER-FICTIONALCHARACTER See my comment re using text not images/links. If you are going to edit, please edit everything. But in a case like this just comment & tell the poster to use text not images/links. PS Your edit was too small for a reviewed edit, it shouldn't have been approved.

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the answers provided will help you fix your code. I just want to expand on why they'll work.

The SQL engine evaluates your `FROM` and your `JOIN`s first, pulling your initial data set into memory. At that point, because you've used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, all the rows you're expecting are still there.

After that, it applies your `WHERE` clause. In this case, your `WHERE` clause includes `job.job_date BETWEEN '2018-10-21' AND '2018-10-30'`, so at that point the engine filters off all of the rows that don't meet that criteria. This effectively makes the results from your `LEFT JOIN` exactly the same as the results you would get with an  `INNER JOIN`.

The best answer, which has been suggested a number of times, is to move that filtering criteria to your `ON` clause. An alternative that will work, and that sort of demonstrates that the results are really all there to begin with, is to add the `IS NULL` possibility to your existing `WHERE` clause:

```
...
WHERE 
  NOT ("users"."status" = 'F') 
  AND
  (
    (job.job_date BETWEEN '2018-10-21' AND '2018-10-30')
    OR
    job.job_date IS NULL
  )
```

Using the condition on the `JOIN`, though, will perform better because you're pulling fewer records into memory in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of this bite:

```
AND job.job_date BETWEEN '2018-10-21' AND '2018-10-30'
```

You need to move it to the LEFT JOIN like:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs_job AS job on employee.id = job.employee_id
AND job.job_date BETWEEN '2018-10-21' AND '2018-10-30'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use your other condition in ON cluase instead of where clause

```
SELECT "employee"."id",
       "employee"."created",
       SUM(job.minutes) AS job_minutes
FROM users_employee AS employee
    INNER JOIN users_user AS users ON (employee.user_id = users.id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs_job AS job on employee.id = job.employee_id
and "users"."status" <> 'F' AND job.job_date BETWEEN '2018-10-21' AND '2018-10-30'
GROUP BY
    employee.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the condition on the *last* table to the `on` clause.  The filtering on the second table stays in the `where`:

```
SELECT "employee"."id",
       "employee"."created",
       SUM(job.minutes) AS job_minutes
FROM users_employee employee INNER JOIN
     users_user users
     ON employee.user_id = users.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     jobs_job job 
     ON employee.id = job.employee_id AND
        job.job_date BETWEEN '2018-10-21' AND '2018-10-30'
WHERE "users"."status" <> 'F' 
GROUP BY employee.id;
```

The logic works this way because left outer joins produce results with `NULL` values from the second table in the `JOIN`.  These `NULL` values can be filtered out in the `WHERE` clause.