# Issue in SQL query with Left Join

Tags: sql, left-join, hana

I'm trying to fetch data from Hana database integrated.

Following is the SQL:-

```
 SELECT alert.UNIQUE_ALERT_ID, 
        alert.MARK_AS_DELETED, 
        data.VALUE
 FROM "ab"."t-systems.testDB::tables.Alerting" alert
      LEFT JOIN 
      "ab"."t-systems.testDB::tables.AdditionalData" data
      ON alert.UNIQUE_ALERT_ID = data.UNIQUE_ALERT_ID
      AND data.KEY='batchId'
      AND alert.MARK_AS_DELETED != '1';
```

Problem is I'm getting all the data where Mark_As_Deleted is also 1. The != is not working properly. I tried with <> but problem still persists. I guess something wrong with my Left Join query because when I remove all join and make a simple Select query with same condition as MARK_AS_DELETED != '1', I get proper output but not with Left Join. 
I tried re-writing my Left Join query with all possible ways (like moving the condition up & down, etc) but nothing worked.

I would really appreciate if you someone can help me here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `left join`, conditions on the *first* table should normally go into a `where` clause.

So I think you want:

```
SELECT alert.UNIQUE_ALERT_ID, alert.MARK_AS_DELETED, data.VALUE
FROM "ab"."t-systems.testDB::tables.Alerting" alert LEFT JOIN
     "ab"."t-systems.testDB::tables.AdditionalData" data
      ON alert.UNIQUE_ALERT_ID = data.UNIQUE_ALERT_ID AND
         data.KEY = 'batchId'
WHERE alert.MARK_AS_DELETED <> '1';  -- remove the quotes if this is a number
```

This follows from the definition of a `LEFT JOIN`.  A `LEFT JOIN` keeps all rows in the first table, regardless of whether the `ON` clause evaluates to true, false, or `NULL`.

So, a condition on the *first* table is ignored.  The rule is conditions on the first table go in `WHERE` and on the second table, in the `ON`.

Comment: @vinod827: In other words: You made `alert.MARK_AS_DELETED != '1'` a mere join condition by placing it in the `ON` clause. So you select *all* rows from `alert` and only consider *joining* `data` records for unmarked `alert` rows.