# Populate records with default values if query doesn't result any results

Tags: sql, hive

I have a query in `Hive` like below. This query works as expected for me.

```
select 
case 
when account_number = '4122268949' then 'Operating'
when account_number = '4127343176' then 'Reserve'
when account_number = '4125604850' then 'sFBo'
when account_number = '2651133000' then 'IDEAL'
when account_number = '4496851031' then 'PwB'
end as account_name,
account_number, 
count(distinct(file_name)) as file_name_count, 
count(*) as total_file_count, 
case when count(*) >=1 then 'Minimum_expected_files_processed' 
else 'Files_not_received_today' 
end as Files_validation
from 
database.table 
where 
account_number in (
'4122268949', 
'4127343176', 
'4125604850', 
'2651133000', 
'4496851031'
) 
group by 
account_number) tb1;
```

Question:

If in the table I don't have any records for `4496851031` and `4127343176` account_numbers.

Then I want the result to have

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|account_name| account_number| file_name_count| total_file_count|                  Files_validation|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Operating  |     4122268949|              2 |              20 | Minimum_expected_files_processed | 
| Reserve    |     4127343176|              0 |              0  |         Files_not_received_today |
| sFBo       |     4125604850|              3 |              22 | Minimum_expected_files_processed |
| IDEAL      |     2651133000|              1 |              1  | Minimum_expected_files_processed |
| PwB        |     4496851031|              0 |              0  |         Files_not_received_today |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> > Edit

when I filter the `database.table` to add extra where clause that returns only `3` account numbers, I am unable to achieve what I want

`sample query`

```
select accounts.name as account_name,
   accounts.number as account_number,
   count(distinct b.file_name) as file_name_count,
   count(b.file_name) as total_file_count,
   case when count(b.file_name) >= 1 then 'Minimum_expected_files_processed' 
        else 'Files_not_received_today' 
        end as Files_validation
from accounts
left join db.table b on b.account_number = accounts.number
where b.load_date >= '2019-08-20'
group by accounts.number, accounts.name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a table with account numbers and names (let's call it `accounts`). Then you can `LEFT JOIN` that to your other table to get the results you want:

```
select accounts.name as account_name,
       accounts.number as account_number,
       count(distinct table.file_name) as file_name_count,
       count(table.file_name) as total_file_count,
       case when count(table.file_name) >= 1 then 'Minimum_expected_files_processed' 
            else 'Files_not_received_today' 
            end as Files_validation
from accounts
left join `table` on table.account_number = accounts.number
group by accounts.number, accounts.name
```

If you *really* don't want to create a table for accounts, you can rewrite the query using a derived table for the account data:

```
select accounts.name as account_name,
       accounts.number as account_number,
       count(distinct table.file_name) as file_name_count,
       count(table.file_name) as total_file_count,
       case when count(table.file_name) >= 1 then 'Minimum_expected_files_processed' 
            else 'Files_not_received_today' 
            end as Files_validation
from (select '4122268949' as number, 'Operating' as name
      union
      select '4127343176' as number, 'Reserve' as name
      union
      select '4125604850' as number, 'sFBo' as name
      union
      select '2651133000' as number, 'IDEAL' as name
      union
      select '4496851031' as number, 'PwB' as name) accounts
left join `table` on table.account_number = accounts.number
group by accounts.number, accounts.name
```

Comment: I am still getting only records that are present in my source table I have tried both the options you have shared

Comment: @nmr it works fine for me in both forms: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jW3yr93R7dzsKrJm6WwEKS/1

Comment: your code is working fine after adding `name` column in group by clause. But when I use a where clause in `table` that gives me only 3 records I am unable to get what I require. Please see edited question

Comment: Please check now

Comment: @nmr can you please include the new query. I'm pretty sure I know what the issue is but need to see it

Comment: added the query. Please check

Comment: @nmr yeah, your problem is that the `where b.load_date >= '2019-08-20'` filters out any rows where `b.account_number` might have been `NULL`. Add that condition to the `LEFT JOIN` instead, i.e. `left join db.table b on b.account_number = accounts.number
and b.load_date >= '2019-08-20'`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows