# Join multiple tables and apply where on multiple tables and then group by in access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, group-by

I have 7 tables as follows.

```
Location:

| Id | LocationName |
|----|--------------|
|    |              |
|    |              |
|    |              |


BSAReporting:

| Id | AttendanceDate | LocationName | BSA |
|----|----------------|--------------|-----|
|    | 12/19/2019     | America      | 150 |
|    |                |              |     |
|    |                |              |     |


HSEGroupMeetings:

| Id | AttendanceDate | LocationName | BSA |
|----|----------------|--------------|-----|
|    | 12/19/2019     | America      | 150 |
|    |                |              |     |
|    |                |              |     |

LTI

| Id | AttendanceDate | LocationName | LTI        |
|----|----------------|--------------|------------|
|    | 12/19/2019     | America      | 12/12/2012 |
|    |                |              |            |
|    |                |              |            |

MHReporting:

| Id | AttendanceDate | LocationName | MH  |
|----|----------------|--------------|-----|
|    | 12/19/2019     | America      | 150 |
|    |                |              |     |
|    |                |              |     |

NMReporting:

| Id | AttendanceDate | LocationName | NM  |
|----|----------------|--------------|-----|
|    | 12/19/2019     | America      | 200 |
|    |                |              |     |
|    |                |              |     |

StopSafetyObservationCycleReporting:

| Id | AttendanceDate | LocationName | SSOC|
|----|----------------|--------------|-----|
|    | 12/19/2019     | America      | 950 |
|    |                |              |     |
|    |                |              |     |
```

I need to join all these 7 tables and fetch sum of TotalEntries from all Tables while 
filtering the records on AttendanceDate(WHERE Table.AttendanceDate = [external parameter]) and applying group by on LocationName from LocationMaster.

**What i have tried:**

```sql
SELECT
    LocationMaster.LocationName
  , SUM(MHReporting.DHE)                          AS TotalDHE
  , SUM(MHReporting.Contractors)                  AS TotalContractors
  , SUM(MHReporting.ADNOCContractors)             AS TotalADNOCContractors
  , SUM(NMReporting.NM)                           AS TotalNM
  , SUM(BSAReporting.BSA)                         AS TotalBSA
  , SUM(HSEGroupMeetingReporting.NoOfMeetings)    AS TotalNoOfMeetings
  , SUM(StopSafetyObservationCycleReporting.SSOC) AS TotalSSOC
  , COUNT(LTIReporting.LTI)                       AS TotalLTI
FROM
    (((((LocationMaster
    LEFT JOIN
        NMReporting
    ON
        LocationMaster.ID = NMReporting.Location)
    LEFT JOIN
        LTIReporting
    ON
        LocationMaster.ID = LTIReporting.Location)
    LEFT JOIN
        HSEGroupMeetingReporting
    ON
        LocationMaster.ID = HSEGroupMeetingReporting.Location)
    LEFT JOIN
        BSAReporting
    ON
        LocationMaster.ID = BSAReporting.Location)
    LEFT JOIN
        StopSafetyObservationCycleReporting
    ON
        LocationMaster.ID = StopSafetyObservationCycleReporting.Location)
    LEFT JOIN
        MHReporting
    ON
        LocationMaster.ID = MHReporting.Location
WHERE
    MHReporting.AttendanceDate                            = [DesiredDate]
    OR NMReporting.AttendanceDate                         = [DesiredDate]
    OR BSAReporting.AttendanceDate                        = [DesiredDate]
    OR HSEGroupMeetingReporting.AttendanceDate            = [DesiredDate]
    OR StopSafetyObservationCycleReporting.AttendanceDate = [DesiredDate]
    OR LTIReporting.AttendanceDate                        = [DesiredDate]
GROUP BY
    LocationMaster.LocationName
;
```

But the results are not as desired. Some data was missing.

Desired Output:

[image]

> Forget about the horizontal alignment. I am not using a cross tab query.its just a slide. I will be using vertical alignment only.

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired result. Why Count instead of Sum for TableF?

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question. Count is just for one table. rest all sum. because that one table contains date values and i dont need to sum them rather just a count..

Comment: [Format SQL](https://www.sqlinform.com/online-sql-formatter/) . Still missing sample data, and tables structure,

Comment: What do u mean by sample data. I have already posted the original data in the BSAreporting table's screenshot

Comment: Sample data for all tables, as [text-table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to play with (we won't extract that from an image!)

Comment: Ok. Pls give me some time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Join not returning all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows)

Comment: @Nick hi Nick. Actually my question is not about left join. The problem is i need all the data(full join) but not supported in  access. I need a query that will return all records from all tables matching the date supplied in where criteria and finally gorup the results by the location name from location table

Comment: Hey @ComputerVersteher. I've added the text-tables now..@Nick is helping with a solution.

Comment: That data should produce your expected resul ;)  and you don't give reliable infos, as tables don't contain the fields from your query (e-g. Location)! And there are Lookup-Fields (Location too)? Also Multi-Value fields? You should inform on that (and it's recommended to avoid them, as they hide the real data-stucture).

Comment: You should improve your table-structure (revealed by @Nick's subqueries), as a new`Employee Category`would force you to add an addtitional field to`MHReporting`. If you create a field for the category-type (and a lookup table for them) you could have unlimited categories. Inform yourself on`Database-Normalization`, the most important thing. when working with databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to your `WHERE` clauses. When you add a `WHERE` clause to a `LEFT JOIN`, that `WHERE` will fail whenever the row from the `LEFT JOIN`ed table has a  `NULL` value, and remove it from the output (it effectively converts the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`). You need to move the `WHERE` conditions into the `JOIN` conditions instead i.e.

```
SELECT
    LocationMaster.LocationName
  , SUM(MHReporting.DHE)                          AS TotalDHE
  , SUM(MHReporting.Contractors)                  AS TotalContractors
  , SUM(MHReporting.ADNOCContractors)             AS TotalADNOCContractors
  , SUM(NMReporting.NM)                           AS TotalNM
  , SUM(BSAReporting.BSA)                         AS TotalBSA
  , SUM(HSEGroupMeetingReporting.NoOfMeetings)    AS TotalNoOfMeetings
  , SUM(StopSafetyObservationCycleReporting.SSOC) AS TotalSSOC
  , COUNT(LTIReporting.LTI)                       AS TotalLTI
FROM
    (((((LocationMaster
    LEFT JOIN
        NMReporting
    ON
        (LocationMaster.ID = NMReporting.Location AND NMReporting.AttendanceDate = [DesiredDate]))
    LEFT JOIN
        LTIReporting
    ON
        (LocationMaster.ID = LTIReporting.Location AND LTIReporting.AttendanceDate = [DesiredDate]))
    LEFT JOIN
        HSEGroupMeetingReporting
    ON
        (LocationMaster.ID = HSEGroupMeetingReporting.Location AND HSEGroupMeetingReporting.AttendanceDate = [DesiredDate]))
    LEFT JOIN
        BSAReporting
    ON
        (LocationMaster.ID = BSAReporting.Location AND BSAReporting.AttendanceDate = [DesiredDate]))
    LEFT JOIN
        StopSafetyObservationCycleReporting
    ON
        (LocationMaster.ID = StopSafetyObservationCycleReporting.Location AND StopSafetyObservationCycleReporting.AttendanceDate = [DesiredDate]))
    LEFT JOIN
        MHReporting
    ON
        (LocationMaster.ID = MHReporting.Location AND MHReporting.AttendanceDate = [DesiredDate])
GROUP BY
    LocationMaster.LocationName
```

Note also that you are likely to end up with incorrect counts due to row duplication, so you may need to rewrite your query along these lines:

```
SELECT
    LocationMaster.LocationName
  , COALESCE(MHReporting.DHE, 0) AS DHE
  , ...
FROM
    LocationMaster
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Location
                , AttendanceDate
                , SUM(DHE) AS DHE
                , SUM(Contractors) AS Contractors
                , SUM(ADNOCContractors) AS ADNOCContractors
           FROM MHReporting
           WHERE MHReporting.AttendanceDate = [DesiredDate]
           GROUP BY Location, AttendanceDate) MHReporting ON LocationMaster.ID = MHReporting.Location
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...
```

Comment: Synatx error. Missing operator in query expression.(Fist code)

Comment: @Thameem does it say on what line?

Comment: Error in Line number: 9 (ms access)

Comment: @Thameem my bad - I forgot Access *requires* parentheses around multiple joins. See my edit.

Comment: It says.. Error: Join Expression not supported. Its pointing line no 16  NMReporting.AttendanceDate = [DesiredDate]

Comment: @Thameem I think you need to enclose the `ON` conditions in parentheses too... see my edit

Comment: @Thameem no worries - sorry about the missteps along the way but I'm glad we got it working in the end.

Comment: @Thameem your question is much improved from the original but it is still missing expected and actual output data that shows the problem. The sample data you provided would not demonstrate what the actual issue was.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204703/discussion-between-thameem-and-nick).