# MariaDB - LEFT JOIN does not return all rows

Tags: sql, mariadb, left-join, greatest-n-per-group, mariadb-10.1

(Before you mark this as duplicate, please read the question).
I have two different tables, `Bot` and `Switch`.

```
Bot
ID | Info | Active
------------------
0  | abc  |     1
1  | def  |     1

Switch
Date       | Activated | BotID | User
-------------------------------------
2020-01-01 |         1 |     0 | John
2020-01-02 |         0 |     0 | John
```

For each bot, I would like to retrieve its latest status, which means: for each bot, I would like to know  whether latest row's `Activated` field was `1` or `0`. In order to return a result for those bots who do not have an entry in the `Switch` table, I tried to use a `LEFT JOIN` statement. Here is the query:

```
SELECT IFNULL(x.Activated, 0) AS Following, b.ID, b.Info
FROM bot b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM switch s1
    WHERE s1.Date IN (
        SELECT MAX(s.Date)
        FROM switch s
        WHERE s.User = 'SomeUsername'
        GROUP BY s.Bot
    )
) AS x ON x.BotID = b.ID
WHERE b.Active = 1
```

My expected result is:

```
Following | ID | Info
---------------------
        0 | 0  | abc
        0 | 1  | def
```

Point is that I'm not getting all rows, instead this query just return a single row:

```
Following | ID | Info
---------------------
        0 | 0  | abc
```

This is strange since I'm using the `LEFT JOIN`. In order to understand what's going on, I separately ran

```
SELECT * 
FROM bot
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM switch s1
WHERE s1.Date IN (
    SELECT MAX(s.Date)
    FROM switch s
    WHERE s.User = 'SomeUsername'
    GROUP BY s.Bot
)
```

Of course, the first query returns:

```
ID | Info
---------
0  | abc
1  | def
```

While the second one returns:

```
Date       | Activated | BotID | User
-------------------------------------
2020-01-02 |         0 |     0 | John
```

I really cannot understand why the `LEFT JOIN` is not keeping both `Bot` rows. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700354/left-join-not-returning-all-rows) question, but I'm not using any outer `WHERE` so it's not my case.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `b.Active` isn't in the schema you've shown

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Sorry about that, I tried to simplify the schema as much as possible. Just edited the question. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Your query should do what you want. Are you able to set up a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Something wrong here. You claim this join works `AS x ON x.Bot = b.ID` but x doesn't contain a  column `Bot` according to your "while the second one returns" output

Comment: Also, I think your "get the latest record" methodology is dodgy; all it does is return a list of dates that are the max for each bot, but it loses which date belongs to which bot. It doesn't coordinate dates by bot. Don't use IN, use EXISTS and coordinate `s1` with `s` on bot and date, or use inner join

Comment: yeah, it's BotID.  But this works correctly. see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=16c09d5ea784ae9539bc6c1799f0bb58)

Comment: What MySQL do you have? I'd do this completely differently on MySQL 8

Comment: So is it still a problem? Are you saying your MySQL and db fiddle give different results for identical scripts? Are the versions the same?

Comment: @CaiusJard Please forgive me, as I said before I had to rewrite the whole schema in order to keep it as simple as possible. I'm not sure what you mean with the second comment. Currently running on 10.1.25-MariaDB.

Comment: did you reproduce it when simplifying?  MariaDB 10.5 works fine with what you have [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=1e10ce7d5588dfe5938afb829cce3f59)

Comment: I think you are hitting a MariaDB bug: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14779

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Just copied and pasted the entire database in the fiddle and it actually works perfectly! Thanks for your help

Comment: Explain why the rows would be kept, with justification by referring to authoritative documentation. Otherwise, why they do what they do is just asking for yet another presentation of the language with our having no idea where you have misinterpreted before.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Side note; if you're using MariaDB, start out by claiming you're using it, not MySQL. The two products are not the same

Answer (score 1):

Your query should do what you want, as you can see [in this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4963474c7807abed1ef56a20fc74ba8e) (I fixed the issues with column names and slightly changed the data so it is plain to understand it is working). So the problem is either with your data, or your oversimplified the query.

Let me, however, suggest an optimization. Since you only need one column from table `switch`, you can use row-limiting correlated subquery rather than a join:

```
select 
    coalesce(
        (
            select s.activated
            from switch s
            where s.user = 'SomeUsername' and s.botid = b.id
            order by s.date desc limit 1
        ),
        0
    ) as following,
    b.*
from bot
```

I would expect this to be more more efficient that the original version with joins and filtering.

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select coalesce(s.activated, 0) as following, b.*
from bot b
left join (
    select s.*, row_number() over(partition by botid order by date desc) rn
    from switch s
    where user = 'SomeUsername'
) s on s.botid = b.id and rn = 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1272c24f7a3cbefe0772a1803629ed24)**.

---

If your MySQL / MariaDB version does not support window functions, and you need more than one column from `switch`, then you could try and phrase the query a bit differently, to see if the issue still occurs. Consider filtering in the `on` clause of the `left join`, like so:

```
SELECT ...
FROM bot b
LEFT JOIN switch s
    ON s.botid = b.id
    AND s.date = (
        SELECT MAX(s1.date)
        FROM switch s1
        WHERE s1.User = 'SomeUsername' AND s1.botid = s.botid
    )
WHERE b.Active = 1
```

Comment: As Garr suggested I'm probably hitting a MariaDB bug, since my query works in the fiddle. Thanks a lot for your answer though, better performance is certainly something I'm looking for, and your query actually doesn't raise any issues.

Comment: Just another question, what if I also need to retrieve another column from `switch`? Never used `COALESCE` before and I'm not sure what to do, can't find much on the internet.

Comment: @DamiToma: If you want more than one column, then a correlated subquery is not adequate (you would need to repeat the column for each and every additional column). I added another query in the answer, that does the same thing as your original query but with a different technique - maybe that won't hit the bug. NB: `COALESCE()` is just lke `IFNULL()` (but it's standard SQL, while the latter isn't).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer is extremely helpful. Looking forward to improving my SQL skills!

Answer (score 1):

As you're on Maria 10.5, you can use analytics to make your life easier:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT 
    COALESCE(s.Activated, 0) AS Following,
    b.ID, 
    b.Info, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.ID ORDER BY s.Date DESC) rn
  FROM 
    bots b
    LEFT JOIN switch s ON s.Bot = b.ID
  WHERE b.Active = 1
)

SELECT * FROM x WHERE rn = 1
```

This should be fairly easy for you to edit - at it's heart it's a standard left join bots:switch. Sometimes you get a switch, sometimes not. When you get a switch you get the most recent date from the row_number. If you remove the `WHERE rn = 1` you'll see you get all dates, but there's an rn column that is an incrementing counter that restarts from 1 when the bot id changes. The `rn = 1` rows are what you want because the counter increments as the date goes from recent to past

Adding more columns to this is simply a case of adding them to the select inside the WITH block

`COALESCE` is nothing magical; it's like IFNULL but can have loads of arguments. It works its way from left to right giving back the first one that isn't null. When used with 2 arguemnts it's just like IFNULL, but it has the benefit that it works in all major spec compliant databases, whereas IFNULL/NVL/ISNULL changes name all the time

---

If analytics aren't available a typical "get latest row" looks like :

```
WITH switchlatest AS (
    SELECT s.*
    FROM
      switch s
      INNER JOIN (SELECT bot, MAX(date) maxd FROM switch GROUP BY bot) maxd
      ON s.bot = maxd.bot AND s.date = maxd.date

)
```

You can left join this `switchlatest` in just like you would `switch`

It behaves a bit differently to rownum if there are multiple dates that are the the same as true max (they're all returned, rownum route only returns one)

General pattern for database versions that don't support WITH

```
WITH alias AS 
(
   SELECT columns FROM ...
)
SELECT ... 
FROM 
  table 
  JOIN 
  alias 
  ON ...
```

You copy the word "alias" to be after the closing bracket:

```
(
   SELECT columns FROM ...
) alias
```

Then you copy this whole thing and paste it over the alias in the query:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM 
  table 
  JOIN 
  (
     SELECT columns FROM ...
  ) alias
  ON 
...

Or you can take the WITH and turn it into a view (Replace the WITH with CREATE VIEW) - might as well have it on hand without having to code it into every query,  because you clearly have a business need for "the latest switch" 

Starting to think it might be easier to just upgrade the db!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful answer! Just a note, I'm on MariaDB 10.1.25, not 10.5, check the comments below the question.

Comment: Oof. What a shame.. 10.2 was the introduction of analytics I think

Comment: I added another bit of info

Comment: @CaiusJard: the [`with` clause](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/) was introduced in Maria DB 10.2.1 as well... Here, you can put the subquery directly in the `from` clause though.