# mysql search in left join

Tags: mysql, sql, search, left-join

I have two tables, A and B

table A has this columns:

> id, title

table B has these columns:

> id, content, A_id, type

In table B, A_id is foreign key related to table A.
I want to write a search query that search title in A and left Join to B where `A.id = B.A_id` and search B.content

It is so easy:

```
SELECT A.*, B.content FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id=B.A_id 
WHERE A.title like 'sometitle' AND B.content like 'somecontent';
```

But I have column 'type' in table B that have entries like this: 'good','bad','ugly','good','good'...
when I search 'content' in table B I want that every content to be related to a 'type'. In other words, the query should give me result related to content1 and type good And content2 and type bad...

Example:

TAble A:

```
+----+--------+
| id | title  |      
+----+--------+
|  1 | white  | 
|  2 | blue   | 
|  3 | red    | 
|  4 | white  |
|  5 | blue   | 
+----+--------+
```

table B:

```
+----+---------+------+------+
| id | content | A_id | type | 
+----+---------+------+------+
|  1 | dog     |    1 | good |
|  2 | dog     |    1 | bad  | 
|  3 | cat     |    2 | good | 
|  4 | cat     |    2 | bad  | 
|  4 | cat     |    2 | ugly | 
|  6 | crow    |    3 | good | 
|  7 | crow    |    3 | bad  |  
|  8 | crow    |    3 | ugly |  
|  9 | mouse   |    2 | good |  
| 10 | zebra   |    3 | bad  |  
|    |         |      |      | 
+----+---------+------+------+
I want a query that that its output be this:
+----+-------+---------+------+
| id | title | content | type | 
+----+-------+---------+------+
|  1 | white | dog     | good |   
|  2 | blue  | cat     | bad  | 
+----+-------+---------+------+
```

Comment: please provide some sample data and expected output. Thanks.

Comment: "Search" doesn't mean anything. Explain what rows you want in terms of what rows are input. If you actually say what you want and what is going wrong then you can google that question/problem. This is a faq. Read a definition of left join. It does inner join then adds unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. So if you then ask for result rows that *don't* have a null B column you are removing all the added rows. We say you are "turnining left join into inner join". If you prepared a [mcve] you could remove code until you got something that worked then add code to see where you err.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2479650/3404097 (And of many other hits googling things like 'stackoverflow left join does not return expected rows'.)

Comment: Thank for your comment. I added an example.

Comment: I think the first record of the expected output is not correct, content should be `content5`

Comment: excuse me the previous example was not my desired scenario. the scenario for query and example of it changed. thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a3355/6)

Your query for the expected result was almost correct, just you used the wrong column `content` whether the correct column would be `type`. Look at the below query :

```
SELECT A.id, A.title, B.content, B.type FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B ON A.id=B.A_id 
WHERE (a.title='white' AND B.type='good')
OR (a.title='blue' AND B.type='bad') 
ORDER BY a.id asc
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+----+-------+----------+------+
| id | title | content  | type |
+----+-------+----------+------+
|  1 | white | content5 | good |
|  3 | blue  | content6 | bad  |
|  4 | white | content3 | good |
|  5 | blue  | content9 | bad  |
+----+-------+----------+------+
```

Comment: excuse me the previous example was not my desired scenario. the scenario for query and example of it changed. thanks for help.

Comment: That's strange! That was answer for your described post, if you have now different scenario, you could post a new question!!! You may have more scenarios after couple of days, and for that you should not continue with a post for long time, isn't it? Don't think only about your own benefit, this will not be helpful for the site.

Comment: Dont you have any idea bout question?

Answer (score 0):

I think the query you posted at the end of your question should start like this:

```
SELECT A.id, A.title, B.A_id, B.content, B.type .... (etc.)
```

so that also `B.A_id` is fetched